# How to restart kwin when it is hung?

Tags: kde, kwin

kwin occasionally hangs, which looks like the system not responding to mouse clicks or key presses - although the mouse pointer still moves when you move the mouse!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Log in. Type `killall kwin`.

Press Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Quit all open applications until a terminal becomes visible. Hover the mouse over the terminal application. Type `kwin &`.

What's that, no terminal application open? Tough - you'll just have to reboot.

Comment: I just added an answer that starts kwin from tty1, but I wonder if there is another way (that doesn't require a terminal window to be open already). Presumably you are getting keyboard input back after killing kwin, so after switching back to tty7, can you not just press alt-f2 an run kwin from there?

Comment: Also, my two suggestions mean that you don't have to leave a terminal window open.

Answer (score 43):

As described in the official [Kwin documentation](http://community.kde.org/KWin/Hacking#Restarting_KWin), a good way to go would be to try this either on a running terminal application or on a virtual console (i.e.: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), :

```
DISPLAY=:0 kwin --replace
```

Comment: +1, possibly the same effect as my solution (does `kwin` respond properly to `sigint`?), and certainly not worse. Also, a single command, so better.

Comment: Don't you want to run it in the background?

Comment: Thank you, thank you. Thankfully it crashed on a terminal screen; this saved me a bunch of heartache.

Comment: What if that keyboard shortcut has no effect?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell If Ctrl+Alt+F1 is not working then I think you have a bigger problem than Kwin crashing. You can try the [REISUB MagicSysRq keys](https://askubuntu.com/a/240691/307091) in that situation to see if your kernel is still responsive (also to reboot more safely). It might be disabled on your system for security reasons though. You should search more about the topic before enabling them ofc.

Comment: This worked for me, with the exception that instead of `kwin` it's `kwin_x11` or `kwin_wayland` nowadays

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Robin Green's answer, but this does not require a terminal window to be open already. Instead, specify the display in which to start kwin from tty1. Hence,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access a terminal. Log in.

Type `killall kwin`. Then, type in `DISPLAY=:0 kwin`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to change back to your primary display.

Comment: Shouldn't kwin be run in the background?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost If you like. It's running from tty1, which I wouldn't really use anyway, so I don't find backgrounding kwin necessary.

Answer (score 6):

In later Kubuntu/Plasma 5 `kwin` still hangs/crashes (especially with Intel display drivers [it seems](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2015/10/some-thoughts-on-the-quality-of-plasma-5/comment-page-1/)), but can be more easily restarted: just run in `krunner` - Alt-Space, or Alt-F2: `kwin --replace`

---

Or, create a new **custom shortcut** for that: e.g. Trigger: Meta+K, Action, Command/URL: `kwin --replace`.

In this way `kwin` can be restarted with just the Meta-K shortcut.

Comment: OP said few times in comments and in question that he can't use keyboard

Comment: This still works and helped me today. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Shortcuts

- **krunner**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Or: **tty [number]**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[number]</kbd>

---

#### Command

```
setsid kwin_x11 --replace &
```

---

#### Legend

- **setsid**: creates a new session, so if the terminal is closed kwin still runs.
- **kwin_x11**: only on x11, as in wayland the window manager holds the hole session (no way to restart without closing everything).
- **--replace**: kills any running kwin before launching a new instance.
- **&**: as a separate process.

Comment: That method is also recommended on https://reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a5d2ly/how_do_you_properly_restart_kwin_and_plasmashell/ebpw250/#c

Answer (score 1):

This actually works. It is a nasty bug but at least I can recover now.

In my case, there is no need to go back to the console login using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> but using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> I can simply type `killall plasma-desktop plasma-desktop` and then using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> again,

I can run `plasma-desktop`. Could also be used in a script of course. This way I get back my mouse and I will not lose any work.

Comment: I think that is a slightly different bug, because as I said, I could not use the keyboard at all except to switch to a virtual console. I do mean literally kwin, not plasma-desktop.

Comment: This restarts plasmashell but not kwin. I had the experience of frozen window that crushed kwin: restarting plasmashell would not fix this, but `pkill kwin` would.

Answer (score 0):

If restarting kwin does not help (or if e.g. you have just lost the start menu), it may be plasma. In this case **`plasmashell`** is the one to run as of KDE 5.21 (replacing the old `plasma-desktop`).

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
killall plasma-desktop
plasma-desktop &
```

you could have it all in a bash script in case you need it more times,

*recoverkde.sh*:

```
killall plasma-desktop
plasma-desktop &
```

Comment: And how am I supposed to execute these commands if kwin won't let me do anything on the X display?

Comment: This restarts plasmashell but not kwin. I had the experience of frozen window that crushed kwin: restarting plasmashell would not fix this, but `pkill kwin` would.

Comment: I sometimes do "killall kwin_x11 && kstart5 kwin_x11" , especially when plasma compositor gets slow