# Hotkey to start sync or flushing memory

Tags: kernel, reboot, ext4

I'm asking a question in a very strange manner, i'm sorry. I know what i want, but i don't know exactly how it's called.

I hear somewhere that ubuntu (or linux) has hotkeys , shortcut to start flushing memory.

What i want: for example my laptop stop working, freezing, not responding. But i know that linux kernel is working, and before hot reboot i want do `"safe reboot"` that means, i want sync everything in swap and in memory with my file system before hot reboot.

Also i know that i can kill my X using some hotkey.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04

**UPDATE according flamemyst answer**

Thanks that was exactly what i want.

Just a little addition.

As i read, in Ubuntu some of Magic Commands can be disabled. This link will help
[How to enable commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11002/alt-sysrq-reisub-doesnt-reboot-my-laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you got stuck/frozen GUI, you can try switch to console mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. This should be the first remedy.

In case of really frozen/stuck, probably because of bug in kernel or driver code, you can invoke Magic SysRq Hot Key ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen/SysRq</kbd>+Aditional Key ). Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key for complete additional keys references.

Common use case is to invoke Alt+SysRq+REISUB to safely sync all harddisk and then reboot system. REISUB run the following command in order:

- R = Taking back keyboard from X server
- E = Send SIGTERM to all process
- I = Send SIGKILL to all process
- S = Sync/Flush data to disk
- U = Unmount
- B = Reboot System