# Stuck on login screen, everything plugged in is unresponsive

Tags: 14.04, sound, keyboard, mouse, login-screen

Whilst downloading version 14.04, my mother manually restarted the computer by holding the power button in. Upon restart, the mouse and keyboard do not work, the speakers would not play the start up sound, and a notification indicates there is no internet connection. Pressing the power button does prompt a window with options to restart, lock, or shut down does appear, so I assume the computer itself is functioning fine, but will not recognize anything plugged into it. The keyboard does work in the start up menus, but I don't know how to fix anything from there. Reformatting is not a huge issue if it comes to it, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Try holding Alt + SYSRQ button, and while holding those, press one by one r-e-i-s-u-b buttons. I'll try to post an answer with other solutions, but for now try that. Also, check if you can get into text console, by pressing Alt+Ctrl+F2

Answer (score 0):

**Try magic key reboot**:

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SYSRQ</kbd> , and while holding, press one by one (with interval in 3 seconds or so ), <kbd>R</kbd> - <kbd>E</kbd> - <kbd>I</kbd> - <kbd>S</kbd> - <kbd>U</kbd> - <kbd>B</kbd>

If this doesn't work, try booting from live usb, go into `try ubuntu` , open  terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, and do `lsblk`. Find which partition holds your ubuntu installation ( you should recognize it by size of the partition ), mount it with `mount /dev/sda* /mnt` , where * is the number of your partition. For instance, mine is `/dev/sda5`. Navigate to `/mnt//etc/` and check the file `sysctl.conf` whether it has line `kernel.sysrq=1`, which enables the magic key (source: [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/11194/295286)).

**Attempt live cd rescue for failed update/upgrade**:

All while on live cd/usb:

> 1. sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
> 2. sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
> 3. sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
> 4. sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
> 5. sudo chroot /mnt
> 6. apt-get update
> 7. apt-get upgrade

In addition I would run `update-grub`, but that's not required.
If that doesn't help, repeat steps 1 - 6, and run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gdm` . You will be prompted to select gdm as default desktop manager, so do select gdm. Reboot.
Source: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)

**Backup important data and reinstall the system**

Make sure your keyboard and wireless card don't require proprietary drivers. After you have installed new system and rebooted, go into System Settings -> Software -> Additional Drivers, and make sure you have necessary drivers selected.

Comment: I appreciate the help! Sorry it's taken so long to get back with you. I tried the magic reboot with no success. As soon as I locate my usb I will move on to the alternate methods.