# System doesn't boot - fsck died with exit status 4

Tags: fsck

My system boot, but on status 4/5  it stops and say :

```
fsck died with exit status 4 Checking drive /dev/sda1: 92% (stage 4/5, 1/15) ... fail!
```

What can I do? Please help me

Comment: Is there an option to cancel/skip fsck?

Comment: Try a full fsck from Live installer, but you may be getting hard drive issues. Do you have good backups? Also check drive's Smart Status with Disks. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789