# How to recover EFI boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a dell 15R notebook that used to work very well with windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04.

Today after an apparently normal update the ubuntu desktop became unresponsible than I have to turn it off using power button.

after that I tried to boot again and then I got a bad surprise. it failed. :(

Now the boot menu is not appearing anymore, it is booting directly into windows

could someone give me a help, please?

---

after trying Boot Repair tool the machine have boot into the Windows 10 directly.

The I turn it off and on pressing F12.

In the boot page I saw that Ubuntu and Windows are there and the mode if EFI Secure Off

Fortunately I was able to boot ubuntu selecting it in the menu. and did some backup :)

The strange is that grub menu that was presented is full of new entries some related to EFI.

The link for the Boot Repair report is  http://paste2.org/MPhXHdbP (before) and http://paste2.org/n6v0XDZM

Any idea ?

Comment: Boot from a live Ubuntu USB/DVD and run BootRepair.

Comment: How you shutdown can damage system, requiring fixes. You may need fsck to repair system. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 and:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1509765&p=12543274#post12543274 Then run Boot-Repair, if not fixed, post the link to the Summary Report.

Comment: If Boot Repair doesn't help, be sure to post the URL that Boot Repair reports; this will show us detailed diagnostics on your system.

Comment: Hi, Boot Repair didn't work as expected. I edit the question and added the links from the report. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair the GRUB. Do the following

Boot using a Live USB/CD of Ubuntu. Use Boot Repair to fix the problem.

After booting with Live USB/CD, run following command in terminal:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use Recomended Repair. This will install GRUB back :)
[image: screenshot of boot-repair]

Comment: Thanks all. finally I found the time to buy a pen-drive and set-up ubuntu on it. have generated the report before let boot repair starts to work. http://paste2.org/MPhXHdbP

Comment: Boot Repair didn't work as expected. I edit the question and added the links from the report. thanks

Comment: Seems like u installed one in uefi and other os in legacy(bios)..that time only bootrepair makes a mess

Answer (score 0):

Did you do what your (second) report tells you to do at the end:

If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
paste.ubuntu.com ko (), using paste.debian
paste.debian.net ko (), using paste2