# After dual boot with Windiws 10, Ubuntu can't start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I get that black screen, but if I enter in recovery mode, and then I repair broken packages, Ubuntu starts fine. The problem is that I must do that every time.

[image]

Comment: First try a full fsck. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Then if still issues check that hard drive is ok with Disks and icon in upper right corner & Smart Status.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you allready have updatet or reinstalled grub?

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX (replace sdX with your device..)    
sudo update-grub
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running `sudo update-grub`. The `grub-install` is not necessary as Linux boots already.