# 16.04 Ubuntu/Windows 10 dual boot: Windows boots fine, Ubuntu goes to blue screen

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows

I have used a dual-boot setup for several weeks, with no problems. The other day, Ubuntu stopped booting. I can still boot Windows without issues, but the Ubuntu partition goes to a blue screen.

It will show the Ubuntu logo and work for a little bit, then I get this (sorry the picture isn't great, it came and went quickly)
[image: Ubuntu error message]

The only advice I could find was hit `ctrl + shift + f1` to boot to the command line and run `apt-get upgrade`, but that command didn't take me anywhere.

I'd love to recover the install, but if I can't repair it, is there a way to access data on the Ubuntu partition from my Windows partition?

Thanks.

Comment: *" is there a way to access data on the Ubuntu partition from my Windows partition?"* - no, but you will be able to access it if you boot a live Linux USB drive or DVD

Comment: You can try a full fsck from live installer on all your ext4 partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789