# Files and config suddenly disappeared

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery

Today a lot of files in my Home folder suddenly disappeared after a reboot. Also, it seems like all my configurations made to the system were resetted (e.g. my color scheme and config files for fish shell are gone). On the other hand all my installed programs are still there. I am sure that I did not just delete everything by an accidental `sudo rm *` or something like that.

I'm using a Dual boot system with Kubuntu 17.04 installed on a SSD and Windows 10 installed on a HDD with the HDD split up in a few partitions. When accessing those partitions everything is still there. It seems that only the SSD is affected.

Has someone experienced something like this? Can someone recommend a way to diagnose and (hopefully) fix the problem? I'm gonna try some hard drive checking and later post the results here.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
There were two partitions on the SSD, one small boot partition and one ext4 partition on which ubuntu was installed.

When running `e2fsck -f -p -v /dev/nvme0np2` on the ubuntu partition this is the result:

```
298506 inodes used (1.91%, out of 15597568)
     121 non-contiguous files (0.0%)
     279 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
         # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
         Extent depth histogram: 269963/52
 4113962 blocks used (6.59%, out of 62383360)
       0 bad blocks
       2 large files
  235222 regular files
   33641 directories
       7 character device files
       0 block device files
       0 fifos
      19 links
   29626 symbolic links (28475 fast symbolic links)
       1 socket
 ------------
  298516 files
```

Contents of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=a8b58d53-3ab0-4026-8be8-6128e0498d05 /               ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=3788-58D0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sda6 /media/me/Share ntfs defaults 0 0
```

Comment: That is typical is /home is a separate partition and did not mount. It defaulted to a new /home with nothing in it. If a separate partition first try fsck. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Use your partition not example sdb1 shown, you may want to run on all ext4 partitions, only run from live installer so partition(s) are unmounted.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and added the result as an edit. It does not seem to find any errors

Comment: If not a separate partition, not sure how you could lose just /home? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Some do not get good link, if so, copy & paste manually to a pastebin site & post link.

Comment: Here is the output of boot-info: https://paste2.org/aKv9HGYm

Comment: Not seeing anything as an issue. Script does not parse NVMe drives fully. You show no fstab but must have one. Post above this: `cat /etc/fstab`.  Separately you left Windows fast start up on. If directly booting Windows from UEFI and not needing to use any NTFS partitions that may be ok. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Posted my fstab above.
Thats weird because the first thing I did after setting up Windows was disabling the fast startup.

Comment: Windows on updates will turn fast start up back on. And often updates are in background and you do not know they were done. Is the missing info from your mount of your shared NTFS partition? As if Windows has fast start up on, that all NTFS partitions are hibernated & Linux NTFS driver will not normally mount.

Comment: The files that disappeared were not on the Share partition. Only the profiles for firefox and thunderbird that were shared between the two OS this way, were on that partition.

Comment: Then it probably is Windows fast start/hibernation, make sure that is off.  Possibly the NTFS partition needs chkdsk from Windows. Those are the two main reasons the Linux NTFS driver will not mount a NTFS partition as read/write.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. **None** of the missing data was on a ntfs partition. Everything that disappeared was in my `/home/me` folder on the second partition of the SSD that was mounted as `/` (an ext4 partition). So why could windows hibernation be the reason for the data to disappear?
I followed your advice and ran `chkdsk` on all the windows partitions but no errors were found.

Comment: If the data was in your ext4 partition and not linked from another partition then it is a mystery. I link folders like /Documents to another partition & folder in that partition, so in my case the /mnt/data partition is the one that really has data. Do you have Firefox & Thunderbird working, now?

Comment: Firefox and Thunderbird are working and the profiles are there - at least on Windows. I did not set the profiles up again on Ubuntu yet.