# Running fsck manually

Tags: fsck, documentation

In a recent reboot of Ubuntu, which failed, I get the message to run fsck manually. How do I do so. I may have a bad HD sector, and it may be easier to reinstall Ubuntu. I'm a newbie, so bear with me.

Comment: See this, but use your ext4 partition(s) not sdb2 as in example. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Answer (score 3):

Note: For 18.04 and newer, see [my new instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1191343).

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Hey. And what if `fsck` is to be performed on `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`? Is this answer still applicable?

Comment: @Duos Good question. The answer is, yes it is.

Comment: Then I don't know. I was dropped into an initramfs prompt on boot with the message `dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root contains a file system with errors, check forced`. I executed `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y` and I now have an infinite scroll of random numbers all over my screen. What's this mean?

Comment: Before I executed the previous command, I first tried `fsck /dev/sda1` and the report was that it was `clean`. Rebooting the computer did nothing but return me back to initramfs. Doing the same inside Recovery Mode has no effect as well.

Comment: @Duos Didn't I help you with a network issue recently? If fsck is giving you a scrolling list of numbers, you may have a big hard disk problem. Please start a new question with all of the information, and include a screenshot/picture of the scrolling list for me to see. What started all of this (answer this in the new question). Flag me there with a comment starting with "@heynnema" so I'll get notified.

Comment: Here it is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149828/infinite-scrolling-random-numbers-on-screen-after-running-fsck-manually

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but if anyone else reaches this thread, here's what worked for me:
The error screen said something about an orphaned linked list at dev/mmcblk0p2 and that I had to run `fsck` manually. The simple solution is to do exactly what it says: run `fsck` on the corrupted filesystem.

```
fsck /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

This will prompt you through the fixing of the filesystem easily and smoothly.