# Ubuntu 17.10 does not start and remain in loop

Tags: dual-boot, reboot

I have dual boot system, ubuntu 17.10 runs side by side with Windows 10. Ubutu 17.10 was running smoothly, until recently I pulled the recent update. When I start the computer, it remains in loop with the message as shown below:

[image: This is a screen shot during the rooboot]

Furthermore, if I go to  first recovery mode (1.37), I get this message:

[image: This is screenshot taken during the reboot with recovery mode]

The ubuntu starts only when I select the last recovery mode (1.36).

How should I fix this issue? Please advise.

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004955/running-fsck-manually/1004964#1004964 and see if it resolves your problem. Report back. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: I tried the link given by you. unfortunately it didn't help.  Thanks.  Anyways, I moved to ubuntu 18.04