# tr: command not found

Tags: 18.04, bash, tr

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and recently I keep getting this error when running bash scripts: `tr: command not found`. The `tr` does not exists in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`. Also installed `coreutils` but still no luck. How can I add this command to my shell?

`which tr` returns nothing. This is what apt says about `coreutils`:

```
coreutils is already the newest version (8.28-1ubuntu1).
```

I get `Command 'tr' not found` so nothing is overriding it. `/usr/bin` is in my `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tr` is contained in the `coreutils` package, but if this package was installed before a simple `apt install` will not restore it. To **re**install the package use `apt-get`’s `--reinstall` option:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```

If you didn’t (re)move the missing binary `/usr/bin/tr` there might be something wrong with your system, [run `fsck` on the partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/1004964/507051) for a filesystem check and (if necessary) repair.