# Infinite scrolling random numbers on screen after running fsck manually

Tags: boot, 18.04, initramfs, fsck, busybox

Yesterday I had a lot of Java applications open that were eating into my RAM. I'm a Java developer so what I usually do in such situations is just reboot. I closed all the apps and did a shutdown. On booting, I was dropped into an `initramfs` prompt. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oTGb.jpg

`initramfs` is something I had no clue about, so I just did an `exit`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT7Ez.jpg

The suggestion was to run `fsck` on the mentioned filesystem, which I did: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MEKS.jpg The last line here appears to be the one that causes the mess that follows. Typing `y` for `yes` and my entire screen becomes a top-to-bottom infinite scrolling random numbers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLRD7.jpg

How do I get back control of my computer?

**UPDATE**: Screenshots of the SMART Data -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQPAB.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQqlL.jpg

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94707/discussion-on-question-by-duos-infinite-scrolling-random-numbers-on-screen-after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re: *"I was dropped into an initramfs prompt on boot with the message dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root contains a file system with errors, check forced... do a manual fsck."*

At the `initramfs` prompt, type:

`fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` # check the file system

**Update #1:**

`Note: fsck failed to resolve problems`

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- select the "Try Ubuntu" option
- once to the desktop, start the `Disks` app
- select the target disk in the left pane
- click on the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`
- take screenshots of the `SMART Data` and edit them into your question so I can review them
- run the SMART tests

`Note: SMART Data looks fine. HDD is not suspect at this time`

**Update #2:**

- whilst booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, backup whatever data you might still be able to find, to an external source
- start `terminal` and type: `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then visit the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS
- start `gparted` and lay down a fresh GPT partition table (**this will wipe the disk**)
- reinstall Ubuntu (no real need for LVM)
- run `fsck`
- restore data
- set up `Deja Dup` (Backups) to backup to an external source (not /home)

**Update #3:**

Do regular `fsck`s for a while...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I would suggest to check smart data first. *If* the drive in question is broken, and user has no backup, it's better to attempt to make an image of the device *without* other activity.

Comment: @vidarlo That's exactly what we're doing.

Comment: My thanks. I report that I now have a working system and all steps in #2 were followed. Data restore was from a one week old backup on another computer on the local network, and Deja Dup is now doing daily backups to that same computer via SSH. All my code was under Git repositories so for those files, it was a matter of `git pull` from Github.

Comment: @Duos Good news! Did the BIOS check find anything? Keep a close eye for disk errors. If you don't have `smartmontools` installed, you should do that asap. Keep good backups, as we don't really know what caused your problem. Do regular fsck's for a while. See Update #3.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Create a  bootable pen drive and go to Try Ubuntu.
2. Open the terminal and run the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo fsck -f <your_drive_name>
   ```
3. Type `a` when asked and let it run for 4-5 minutes.
4. Once exited normally after the successful run of previous steps, reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

Having a partition with Windows, Grub displays at start-up. When I had the numbers scrolling issue I just pressed power off, then on again and opted for "Advanced options for Ubuntu" the on "recovery mode" and it sorted the issue for me after checking/repairing the damaged partition.