# fsck warning - what does it mean?

Tags: mount, filesystem

I have this problem, please help me!
I don't want to reinstall ubuntu as I've done several times

```
nico@home:~$ sudo umount /dev/sda3
umount: /: target is busy.
nico@home:~$ fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sda3 is mounted.



WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.


Do you really want to continue<n>? no
check aborted.
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
open: Permission denied
```

Comment: You can't fsck your mounted disk safely.  You need to boot into a LiveUSB / Installer environment and run the fsck from there.

Comment: you also can't fsck without sudo on a normal prompt And why would you consider doing fschk on a partition/disk that is in use?  If the directory where you did this from on /dev/sda3 perhaps? Or do you have another session open? if so umount will fail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running fsck manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004955/running-fsck-manually)

Comment: You need to boot into a LiveUSB / Installer environment and run the fsck from there.
I've tried that, but I can't acced to the directory