# New to Linux and recovering from windows 10 update. Recomended solutions not working?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I've been dual-booting Ubuntu (EFI) and Windows in and made the mistake of allowing windows to perform the "Fall Creators update."

Since the update, my system boots to GRUB but outputs only "Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported." I tried to boot each of the partitions that ls listed, but in each case got an error that the filesystems was unknown. Windows boots fine if I exit GRUB.

I'm very new to linux, but after reading through similar threads it seemed like Windows might have damaged or deleted the partition table. I used an old Ubuntu usb to run boot-repair, which did not resolve the problem. I also tried to mount the linux partition to reinstall GRUB, but have been unable to due to an generic error message.

Here are the summaries give by fdisk, parted, and gparted, but I don't really know what to make of them other than that they appear to disagree about the size of my Ubuntu partition, and that only fdisk appears to recognizes the Ubuntu partition.

[image: Parted and fdisk -l results]

[image: gparted screen shot]

I'm feeling very over my head. I've been using Ubuntu for everything except some light gaming, and am very concerned about data loss at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

Update: Per oldfred's suggestion I ran e2fsck which told me I had a bad superbloc. I've tried restoring from a backup, but every backup gives "bad magic number in superbloc." At this point I'd be happy to wipe my hd and start over, I just need data back...

Comment: For the data loss you may want to boot up your system using a livecd and copy any critical information to an external drive, just in case your tests may affect/rewrite portions of the disk

Comment: Thanks versvs, not sure how I can do that though. The file system on the partition is not being recognized and sudo mount /mnt/ returns an error.

Comment: Fdisk sees sda6 as Linux and sda7 as swap, but parted does not? I might try e2fsck on sda6 first from live installer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your help. Here was the result of e2fsck. It doesn't look positive...       " 2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>"

Comment: Did you try the alternative superblock(s)? Remove first inode to use alternative superblock:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1682038
List backup superblocks:
`sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda6 | grep -i backup`
then use backup superblock, 32768 is just an example, try several