# No OS found, SMART Self-Test fails, individual tests all OK

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

About two months ago I created a dual boot on my HP Pavilion x360 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. On Friday, my laptop wouldn't boot and told me it couldn't find the OS. I ran the diagnostics provided through HP and it told me that SMART tests would pass but the Long DST was failing.

I got Ubuntu 18.04 on a USB and that's what I'm currently on. With that, I ran the Ubuntu-provided diagnostic on my harddrive. It fails the self-test but all the individual tests say they're OK. Is my hard drive failing? Could this be caused by a bad partition? Which test is causing the assessment to fail?

I'm a new Ubuntu user. This is really the first time I've used it. Thanks!

[Here are my partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg9mN.png)

[Here's the SMART test results, part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VKBQ.png)

[Results, part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKXc2.png)

Comment: Failed is not good, but sometimes gives false info. Have you tried chkdsk form Windows on all NTFS partitions and fsck on all Linux partitions? http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: I can't boot to Windows so I can't run chkdsk from Windows.

Comment: I ran e2fsck like the answer you linked to suggested on my Linux partition and got this:

`Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.`
`/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.`
`(i.e., without -a or -p options)`

Comment: I ran `sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda6` and got `Pass completed, 128 bad blocks found. (128/0/0 errors)`

I ran fsck for my linux partition manually, and it fixed a bunch of things. I'm not really sure what it means though. I can post it but it's a lot of lines I'd need to type out by hand.

Comment: Will not be much help. Lots of bad blocks could be an issue. Often it is a quickly growing list of bad blocks that is impending failure. A few is often ok. You should use your Windows repair flash drive to run chkdsk from its repair console.

Comment: I ran GParted, and noticed a warning on my windows partition. Information says:

"Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs."

I ran `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` and then `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3`. The partition "was processed successfully", so I refreshed GParted and it still gave me the same error/warning.

I'm thinking that partition might just be officially useless?

Comment: Unfortunately don't have a windows repair flash drive. This computer just had the default Recovery partition and I never relocated that to a USB.

Comment: No, especially after ntfsfix. The Linux NTFS driver will not mount hibernated nor partitions needing chkdsk. The ntfsfix turns on the chkdsk flag so it will show errors. And usually Windows 8 or 10 turns on fast start up which is just hibernation. Updates to Windows will turn it back on again. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & Find a friend with Windows (same version, ie 64 bit & Windows 10) and use your blank flash drive & create a repair flash drive. Or download new Windows which will work for 30 days but you may be able to use it as repair disk.