# Triple-boot GRUB superblock problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 18.04, kubuntu

I had a dual-boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I wanted to try Kubuntu 18.04.1 as well.

So I've edited my partition table, created ~12GB for that cause, installed Kubuntu on it and my partition table looks as follows (I've also created a separate partition for my home folder in Ubuntu)
[image]

What followed is that Kubuntu's GRUB override Ubuntu's, it showed all the 3 boot options but from that point on I couldn't restart and boot from Windows to either Linux OSs
or from one Linux OS to another without getting this error message

```
fsck.ext4 Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying to open /dev/sdaX
```

[image]
As you can see in every reboot I get the (initrmfs) menu and have to manually fix the filesystem using this command `e2fsck -pb 32768 /dev/sdaX` enter `reboot` and go to the specific entry (mounted sda) that I fixed previously.

It looks like all 3 ext4 linux partitions Kubuntu, Root(ubuntu), Home(ubuntu) share the same
superblock

```
roey@hpx360-13:~$ sudo fdisk -l|grep Linux|grep -Ev 'swap'
[sudo] password for roey: 
/dev/sda6  360892416 385613823  24721408  11.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  424935424 483340287  58404864  27.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  385613824 424935423  39321600  18.8G Linux filesystem
roey@hpx360-13:~$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda6 | grep superblock
dumpe2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-2
  Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32770
  Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98306
  Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163842
  Backup superblock at 229376, Group descriptors at 229377-229378
  Backup superblock at 294912, Group descriptors at 294913-294914
  Backup superblock at 819200, Group descriptors at 819201-819202
  Backup superblock at 884736, Group descriptors at 884737-884738
  Backup superblock at 1605632, Group descriptors at 1605633-1605634
  Backup superblock at 2654208, Group descriptors at 2654209-2654210
roey@hpx360-13:~$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda7 | grep superblock
dumpe2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-2
  Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32770
  Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98306
  Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163842
  Backup superblock at 229376, Group descriptors at 229377-229378
  Backup superblock at 294912, Group descriptors at 294913-294914
  Backup superblock at 819200, Group descriptors at 819201-819202
  Backup superblock at 884736, Group descriptors at 884737-884738
  Backup superblock at 1605632, Group descriptors at 1605633-1605634
  Backup superblock at 2654208, Group descriptors at 2654209-2654210
  Backup superblock at 4096000, Group descriptors at 4096001-4096002
roey@hpx360-13:~$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda9 | grep superblock
dumpe2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-3
  Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32771
  Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98307
  Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163843
  Backup superblock at 229376, Group descriptors at 229377-229379
  Backup superblock at 294912, Group descriptors at 294913-294915
  Backup superblock at 819200, Group descriptors at 819201-819203
  Backup superblock at 884736, Group descriptors at 884737-884739
  Backup superblock at 1605632, Group descriptors at 1605633-1605635
  Backup superblock at 2654208, Group descriptors at 2654209-2654211
  Backup superblock at 4096000, Group descriptors at 4096001-4096003
```

Which might cause a checksum error but on the other hand there was no problem with a dual-boot.

What is the problem here and how can I fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: I have 10 Linux partition, only checked a couple as I think super block is an offset so all partitions usually are the same. Have you run full e2fsck from live installer? https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. Grub only boots working Windows & it may have turned fast start back on with an update.

Comment: @oldfred I've tried e2fsck from live installer (gparted) here is the output https://pastebin.com/gi9e8PrK it didn't help. Yes I can directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu (at startup ESC -> F9 -> Windows boot loader). Windows fast startup is disabled. Like I said it worked find with dual-boot (Ubuntu/Windows) but it doesn't work fine with a triple-boot. Both Ubuntu & Kubuntu have their own GRUB layout, when updating one it overrides the other. I should remove one of them? if so, which one? TNX

Comment: The only difference with Ubuntu flavors or other installs is /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. That is a 3 line file with UUID & partition of the full grub.cfg in an install. I have multiple installs and learned to back up my ESP. But now ususally just edit grub.cfg in ESP back to my main working install. Lets see more details: Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred here you go https://pastebin.com/22JBaE3g TNXALOT

Comment: I do not think I have seen that specific error before. Did you run e2fsck as liked above on all 3 partitions? And does this show any errors? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` Separately have you updated UEFI from HP?