# New motherboard, dual boot doesn't work

Tags: windows, motherboard

I have an ssd with Windows 10 installled and an hdd with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. I use the grub2 for choosing OS.
One day while I was playing in Windows, the pc suddenly powered off, it seems that some VRM (voltage regulator module for cpu current supply) were burned. So I buy a new motherboard.
My problem starts now, I was expecting to everything work fine, but when I was choosing windows it was giving me a signature error (I don't remember exactly), the Ubuntu was booting after minutes but with a lot of errors and fails in boot info screen. So I run boot repair from Ubuntu live CD, now the Ubuntu starts but I get stuck in the emergency mode, the Windows now is boot but it tells me that it need boot repair.
Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: running journalctl -xb in ubuntu emergency mode it gives me some higlited line and i noticed this one:
secureboot:Secure boot could not be determined(mode 0)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question,i have grub menu and i can boot in ubuntu even that it boot with fails and errors(sometimes it boot me into the graphical mode).I can't boot into windows it tells me that it need repair.After running gparted it tells me that "the backup gpt table is corrupt but the primary appears ok",if i agree to go to primary i see that in windows(sda) i have a warning which tells me "Unable to detect file system!Possible reasons are: ....some reasons"

Comment: Thanks for replying. No one else but me reviewed this question so the duplicate flag has been completely deleted. The other answer didn't work, so I'll get to work on this boot problem.

Comment: Any crash or abnormal shutdown often causes file corruption. You need to run chkdsk from a Windows repair disk on all your NTFS partitions and fsck on ext4 partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 UEFI or BIOS installs? What brand motherboard?

Comment: UEFI,Gigabyte  GA-970A-DS3P

Answer (score 0):

These problems are because of hardware changes. You should reset or reinstall Windows and Ubuntu. Also try a startup repair in windows. If not worked, first reinstall Ubuntu and if windows still have problem, reinstall it.
It's good to have a backup from your important files before doing these steps.

Comment: Of course,but i want to avoid this because a have a lot of setting optimized in both os.

Comment: Usually there is no way to avoid reset because of some hardware and software settings. What do you mean of 'optimized settings' exactly?

Comment: Wrong,i forgot to delete this word,i was writting somehting else.I have a lot of settings that i dont want to lose +the re-installation of all my programs.

Comment: If you're signed in to windows 10 by your Microsoft account, don't worry about windows settings. Many of them are synced with your account and will restore when you sign in to new windows installation. About programs and Ubuntu, there is no way.

Comment: If your internet connection is not metered, you shouldn't worry about software re-installation :). A reset is good for your PC performance!

Comment: I dont use a microsoft account.You are absolutely right with reintall all and i can do that in 2-3 days but still i want to avoid this and try to solve it today,the main reason is that i have a lot of programs that i use in the job and i want to avoid spent time to reintal them,so if will go to this option only if i cant solve it today.

Comment: OK. So if you did what I said, Please accept it as a solution later. :)

Comment: Last time I replaced motherboard was with XP. First boot of it, required an approval from Microsoft & that pop-up was behind several other screens. New UEFI systems in UEFI boot mode have product key in UEFI. Ubuntu just booted. But motherboard was similar type as same CPU.

Comment: Hello again! Did you reset your PC?