# dual boot with ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10 . none of them boots

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I have had windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 for a while and it never had any problem. but all on a sudden from yesterday i ccan not get into my computer. Neither the windows nor the ubuntu would boot. Trying to boot windows goes back to black screen and restarts in a while. tried booting into ubuntu it says load your kernel first . so far i have tried this few methods

Grub method: 
set prefix to hd0,msdos10 (msdos10 is my root), then set linux / vmlinuz to root . however grub stuck here forever.

try ubuntu method:
inserted a live usb with ubuntu 18.04.1 selected the try ubuntu . while booted in tried to run the boot repair. but it kept scanning forever

install new ubuntu:

After all these i even tried to freshly install ubuntu 18.04.1 but at some point it gets stuck and waits forever.

I am kind of desperate right now

Comment: That sounds like a lot of partitions you have there. Do you get a grub screen with boot options? Without grub can you boot to Windows from a BIOS boot? Boot to Live Ubuntu and run `sudo parted -l` and post output into question.

Comment: What happens when you try to install 16.04? Can you boot Ubuntu Live from usb and do some stuff there without the computer freezes?

Comment: Did you have an abnormal shutdown. You may have file corruption. And then you need chkdsk on all the NTFS partitions from a Windows repair flash drive and fsck from Ubuntu on all the ext4 partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789