# Ubuntu crashed stuck at GRUB rescue

Tags: grub2, 18.04, grubrescue

So I wanted to open a psd file in Gimp, whole computed froze had to power off (case doesn't have a restart button, dumb, I know).

So after powering up I was stuck at the Grub screen. So I set the root, linux and initrd and booted, and run this command after the first successful boot
`$ sudo update-grub2` followed by `$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda` i got a success message on both account but after I restart PC I am always stuck in the Grub recovery and have to do the whole process again.

Any ideas?
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: From live installer, so ext4 partition(s) are unmounted run fsck. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Answer (score 0):

**Lets check your Ubuntu file system first...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Note**: If dual-boot with Windows, and you've installed a Windows driver to be able to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 file systems, uninstall it asap, as it corrupts ext2/3/4 file systems.

Answer (score 0):

run a live ubuntu
and go to terminal and see your hard device by lsblk
forexample you install ubuntu on /dev/sda1
so write in terminal

> mount /dev/sda1 /dev
>
> grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda

note: in line1 it is sda1 and line2 it is sda
becareful a bout it