# "fsck exited with status code 4" after choosing to boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, command-line, micro-sd

When I turn on my computer, it goes into the Ubuntu interface and asks me what I want to boot into:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced system options for ubuntu 
Windows boot manager (on /dev/sda1)
System setup
```

When I boot into the “Ubuntu” option, it just shows a command prompt that runs a few commands:

```
[   3.075355] sd 4:0:0:0 [sdb] No Caching Mode page found 

[   3.075388] sd 4:0:0:0 [sbd] Assuming Drive cache: write through

/dev/sdb2 contains a file system with errors, check forced

  Inode 2766781 extend tree (at level 2) could be narrower. IGNORED.

Inode 3938804, end of extent exceeds allowed value

 (Logical Block 387, physical block 19229549, Len 1)

/dev/sbd2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.

(i.e., without -a or -p options)

fsck exited with status code 4

The root filesystem on dev/svb2 requires a manual fsck
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)

Enter ‘help’ for a list of built in commands.
(initramfs)
```

This is my only computer and I don’t know much about Linux.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: As it says have you run fsck on sdb2 and maybe other ext4 partitions? You need to use live installer. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Answer (score 2):

I got it done by using:

```
e2fsck -fy /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Yup I ran this command with my drive name instead, then I ran a `exit` command. Ubuntu booted right up.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I just had to run

```
e2fsck -C0 -p on /dev/sdb2
```

(since I was running it from a micro-sd card)

Comment: **LQ Queue Reviewers:** *Self-answer!* Please VTC Q instead!

Comment: What's wrong with the question? Answer seems ok too