# XUBUNTU boot error: fsck exited with status code 4, requires a manual fsck

Tags: xubuntu

my system does not get past those errors and is stuck at initramfs

I tried the different recommendations from:
[Root file system requires manual fsck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885062/root-file-system-requires-manual-fsck/885066#comment1657117_885085)

and

["fsck exited with status code 4" after choosing to boot Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134136/fsck-exited-with-status-code-4-after-choosing-to-boot-ubuntu)   (using /sda1)

but to no progress.

when running fsck I get this error message: "fsck error2: no such file or directory whild dxectuing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda1"

Thanks in  advance

PS: I installed the latest LTS version

Comment: Are you sure that the error message indicated sda1? It sound like running `Boot Repair` might fix your problem. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: thanks,  couldnt get to boot-repair.  Re-installed xubuntu instead.