# Ubuntu USB Stuck on Boot

Tags: boot, usb-installation

I recently got to tinker around with Ubuntu 19.04 after installing it on a USB flash disk, I installed a live iso to a small disk and booted that to do a full install to a larger disk (32GB, ext4, approx. 45% for a partition as / mount point, 45% for a partition as /home mount point, and the remaining 10% for swap). It was all nice, survived 2 reboots, but failed the 3rd reboot. Everything seemed fine, but then it got stuck after loading GNOME Display Manager. Looking around people suggested uninstalling Nvidia drivers, however my install wasn't responding to mouse or keyboard input. Pressing the power button only shut it down, and it still wouldn't boot the next time it was powered on.

Any idea what I can do?

Thank you for your tine.

Comment: After a forced shutdown, you may have corrupted file system and have to run fsck on all ext4 partitions before you can work on original issue.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Flash drives are really slow. Best not to have swap if you have 4GB or more of RAM. And since small partitions  use just / (root). Often a lighter weight flavor like Lubuntu, Budgie, or Mate. I just installed Mate to a 64GB flash drive and made setting changes to reduce writes & it works well.https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417453

Comment: @oldfred Is fsck a linux command? Am I to boot from my live disk, mount the "real" disk, run the command, then shutdown and boot from the "real" disk as normal? (Btw, at no point did I do a force shutdown, I did it the "proper" way, the shutdown button on Ubuntu)

Comment: To run fsck or e2fsck you have to run it from live installer on your installed system or you can set fsck to run on reboot if you are in your system. I thought "power" button meant the hardware power button, not Ubuntu shutdown button.

Comment: @oldfred Alright, I will get to that as soon as I can, in the meantime what else can I do should fsck fail to get my installed system back running, or do I need a full reinstall?

Comment: Then may be best to see details, just to confirm configuration or see it it shows other errors. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred According to fsck the superblock is corrupt, and the boot-repair log suggests its recommended repairs would work (http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pxFp4CjpRY/), however I would like to keep my hard drive clean of anything, everything is to be done on the flash disk, yet I am unable to remove the hard drive physically. Should I try the auto repair or would that mess with my Windows install?

Comment: Do not run autofix. Boot-Repair wants to install grub boot loader to every drive. You want to keep Windows boot loader on Windows drive. You also have older BIOS/MBR installs, but booted live installer in UEFI mode. Since installs are BIOS, only boot live installer in BIOS mode to avoid UEFI and any issues that may create. You do have newer UEFI hardware. Run fsck on all your ext4 partitions on sdc like the example using sdb that I linked to in first comment.

Comment: @oldfred How do I change boot mode to BIOS? The only way I can boot to the live disk is to turn on the laptop and spam F12, then select my disk (it shows up as "USB HDD"), I don't quite see an option to boot as BIOS or UEFI. If I press F2 for boot settings, it already says "legacy mode" (my laptop came with Windows 8, which got upgraded to Windows 10). Do I need to remake my live disk (I created it with Rufus, it doesn't do persistent disks but I didn't think I need it anyway, but it also doesn't allow me to choose BIOS or UEFI, it just says "BIOS/UEFI")?

Comment: Did you re-install Windows as Windows 8 has to be installed in UEFI boot mode by vendor? When you turn on legacy mode that is how system boots installs on hard drive. In UEFI boot menu, your f12 should have two boot options for Ubuntu live installer on flash drive. One usually is UEFI:flash and other flash where flash is name or label of flash drive. Mine defaults to PMAP. Some have settings for allow full USB boot or similar setting somewhere in UEFI settings. Do not know if Rufus correctly creates flash drive for both UEFI & BIOS. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: @oldfred No I didn't, I left it as it is, or at least I don't remember reinstalling Windows 8. Used Windows 8 for a while before Windows 10 came along. As for the boot menu, I really don't see the option to boot as BIOS or UEFI, it really just says "USB HDD: disk-name-and-model".

Comment: @oldfred Update: I retried fsck from my live disk, and this time it worked: it says the installed system is clean, though I found I had to run 2 commands, one for the root partition and one for the home partition, as I separated them. I didn't see my swap partition though. (running fsck on /dev/sdc doesn't work, needed to run it on /dev/sdc1 and /dev/sdc2) || Update 2: it still won't boot though it still gets stuck after loading GNOME Display Manager

Comment: @oldfred Update 3: Turns out I've been running fsck on /dev/sdc, and it thought it wasn't a proper ext4 system. Looking more closely, it seems ext2fs_open2 tried to open /dev/sdc but found "bad magic number in super-block", and so did fsck.ext2. It also says it found a dos partition table in /dev/sdc, which I don't think should be there. Doing fsck on /dev/sdc1 and /dev/sdc2 however, turns up clean with no errors whatsoever, though it doesn't look like it did anything either, just a check.

Comment: The fsck only works on ext4 ( or ext3, ext2) formatted partitions. You cannot run it on a drive as the drive is not formatted. And you do not run it on swap as it is not formatted. Since booting in BIOS mode, MBR(msdos) partitioning is most common. Windows requires MBR for BIOS boot. Ubuntu can boot in BIOS or UEFI from a gpt partitioned drive.What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Is UEFI/BIOS most current version from vendor?

Comment: @oldfred I'm very sure the 2 partitions I have for /home and / are formatted to ext4, according to GParted at least. The laptop I have is no longer sold, but if it helps, it's a Lenovo s410, Intel Core i5-4200U with a GT 720M graphics card. I don't quite know if the BIOS/UEFI has an update, if there is it isn't very apparent how I would download and install the update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93926/discussion-between-404-name-not-found-and-oldfred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I've resorted to reinstalling Ubuntu, it takes less time to do that than fix my disk.

Thank you for your time.