# Can't mount external usb hard disk

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I own Seagate 500GB SATA HDD connected to the casing with the power supply which sits under /dev/sdb

I have successfully created the new ext4 partition using the following commands.

```
sudo fdisk -l


sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

and I formatted the partition with ext4 filesystem

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

I wanted to mount under **/mnt/sdb**

So, I ran the following command.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/sdb
```

***It returns the following error.***

```
mount: /mnt/sdb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

***I tried to fix with fsck. And this error occurs.***

```
root@ninja:~# fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
```

So, I tried **dmesg**

Here is what I got.

```
[ 1504.713877]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1611.157391]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1641.611565]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1642.223147]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1683.013204]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1683.585848]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1918.897280]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2251.717436]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2251.726638]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2312.159638] EXT4-fs (sdb): VFS: Found ext4 filesystem with invalid superblock checksum.  Run e2fsck?
[ 2321.968048] EXT4-fs (sdb): VFS: Found ext4 filesystem with invalid superblock checksum.  Run e2fsck?
[ 2507.225284]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2507.230421]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2578.348564] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Found ext4 filesystem with invalid superblock checksum.  Run e2fsck?
[ 2978.309809] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Found ext4 filesystem with invalid superblock checksum.  Run e2fsck?
[ 3453.311216]  sdb: sdb1
[ 3583.251290]  sdb: sdb1
[ 3591.511303]  sdb: sdb1
[ 3598.683156]  sdb: sdb1
```

Comment: You do not mount a drive, but mount a partition. It looks like you formatted sdb1, but tried to mount sdb. And if corrupted, run e2fsck as it says. or reformat. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: Hey Buddy, @oldfred I tried to Mount /dev/sdb1 and It says "mount: /mnt/sdb: cannot mount; probably corrupted filesystem on /dev/sdb1"

Comment: You posted this: `fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb`, but it has to be `fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb1` with the partition number, not just the drive. More complete e2fsck with parameters posted in link in first comment.