# Ubuntu won't boot: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/media-Datas.mount

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount, fstab

I have a dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04 computer. Windows boots perfectly, but right now Ubuntu won't boot. I get the error

`systemd-fstab-generator [993]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/media-Datas.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?`

and it only allows me to boot into the terminal.

I typed in `journalctl -xb` and found these four errors buried in the log:

- `Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e` (this also shows up when Ubuntu first starts booting)
- The fstab error above, followed by `/lib/systemd/system-generator/system-fstab-generator failed with exit status 1`
- `Timed out waiting for device dev-sdb1.device` (I assume this is a USB device not loading?)
- `Failed to start AppArmor initialization`

How do I fix this? Ideally without touching my Windows installation? I *really* can't afford to break my Windows installation.

Comment: Not sure if this will show anything or not. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair You may need fsck on sdb1 or sda1 whichever it is when you boot flash drive Ubuntu live installer in live mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: You have checked for duplicate (dynamic) entries in fstab?  You haven't also defined one there (dynamically) that you have defined in systemd (statically)

Comment: [Here is my Boot-info file!](https://pastebin.com/c3w3yTTT).

How would I check for duplicate fstab entries? And how would I know which to delete?

Comment: Do you get a grub screen? In your fstab file you have 3 entries for your external drive sdb1. There shouldn't be any entries for it as it's unnecessary as well as a bad idea.

Comment: When you say a grub screen, do you mean the screen where I get to choose whether to start Ubuntu or start Windows? That screen does come up. The errors happen when I choose Ubuntu. Like I said, Windows boots OK.

I don't remember ever editing my fstab file. Would I need to remove lines from it? How would I know what lines to remove? Can I edit it from a live USB?

Comment: OK, I commented out all of the sdb1 entries and it boots now! Is there anything else I should be fixing? The Boot-Repair recommendation said:
```The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of sda5, using the following options:        sda1/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s    use-standard-efi-file```

Comment: @PaulBenson, sorry for the delay in the reply! sda3 is Windows, sda5 is root (I think) and sda8 is /home.

Comment: @JenJen I'll move my earlier comment as part of my answer.