# [Firmware Bug]: TPM Final Events table missing or invalid

Tags: kernel, uefi, tpm

I saw following error message recurring several times on kernel log. Can anybody make an interpretation of it?

```
efi: EFI v2.40 by INSYDE Corp.
efi: SMBIOS=0x8c630000 ESRT=0x8c62ef18 ACPI 2.0=0x8cffd014 RNG=0x8c635198 TPMEventLog=0x8331f018 
efi: seeding entropy pool
random: fast init done
[Firmware Bug]: TPM Final Events table missing or invalid
secureboot: Secure boot enabled
Kernel is locked down from EFI Secure Boot mode; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS but I updated after last restart. I think it was 20.04 before.

Comment: Did you do as it suggests in the error? *see man kernel_lockdown.7

Comment: Yes, it returns: No manual entry for kernel_lockdown.7

Comment: This link is the man page *https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/kernel_lockdown.7.html

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169467/efi-lockdown-cant-boot-ubuntu-16-04-or-windows-10

Comment: I have only one harddisk and no windows installed. Secure boot and UEFI enabled. I didn't have this error before so I don't think I should disable any of this.

Comment: "[Firmware Bug]: TPM Final Events table missing or invalid"  is related to a mismatch between your hardware, bios and the microcode driver and it is (probably) intended for the maintainer of the driver.  The other lines are notifications.

Comment: Just disable Secure Boot, and you are good to go.