# Grub is lost after compiz crashed

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I have a very odd problem. I have a Dell laptop that came with Windows 10 installed. It has an HD with 1TB and a SSD drive with 128GB.
I installed Ubuntu, `/home` and `/swap` partitions are on HD but, as far as I remember, Ubuntu initializer is on SSD. I have Ubuntu 18.04.

The dual boot has always worked perfectly.
However, sometimes I had a known problem with the Compiz (it crashes and then you are forced to shutdown the laptop by pressing and holding the power button). After looking for the solution and trying some commands, it was apparently solved.

Yesterday it happened again (Compiz crashed) but when I rebooted the system the GRUB was lost. I got the message `No bootable devices found`. It couldn't load nor Ubuntu neither Windows. I restarted and went to the BIOS setup. In the boot sequence I still had Ubuntu and Windows as boot options but apparently they were not working. I tried to manually create a boot option for Windows but it worked only once.

Right now I am working with live Ubuntu from a bootable USB drive I created with another laptop.
I looked for many different solutions on different forums and webpages but none worked.
Attached you have my fdisk output:

[image: fdisk output]

**# Solution 1:** `boot-repair` software

I tried to install `boot-repair` (while using live Ubuntu) but it didn't give me the "recommended repair" option, only the "create a bootinfo summary".

**# Solution 2:** `grub-install`

I tried the following sequence:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/ubuntu
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/ubuntu/boot /dev/sda
```

But got the following error:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

After trying some times, I realized that maybe it happened because `/dev/sda4` is my filesystem while my boot for Ubuntu is on SSD drive. The problem is that, after rebooting my laptop a couple of times with live USB Ubuntu, `fdisk` does not show SSD drive anymore (it used to be `sdb`, I think, with some EFI name, maybe). It doesn't appear on GParted as well. I don't know why.

Does anyone have a clue of how to solve it?

---

### UPDATE

For some unknown reason, I rebooted and now the SSD drive `sdb` appears. Here you have my `fdisk` output:

[image: new fdisk output]

Should I try **# Solution 2** above using the respective Linux partition on `sdb`?

Here you have the print of gparted about SSD `sdb`:

[image: gparted]

Comment: Do not mix UEFI systems and BIOS boot of repair. Always boot in UEFI mode. But abnormal shutdown may cause file corruption. Best to avoid if at all possible. But you then need fsck on your ext4 partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: @oldfred by default the boot is in UEFI mode. While I was trying to solve this problem, I tried to activate Legacy Mode but it didn't work because the system didn't identify the pen-drive with Ubuntu image. So I put it back to UEFI. What did you mean by "do not mix UEFI systems and BIOS boot of repair"? Sorry for asking, it's only to make sure I'm not getting the wrong way.

Comment: Boot-Repair would not give the error of missing BIOS boot partition (bios_grub) unless booted in BIOS mode and trying to install the BIOS boot version of grub to a gpt partitioned drive. So at least when you ran Boot-Repair you must have been in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode. Default boot mode in UEFI, is separate from the boot mode you choose for a flash drive or DVD live installer. How you boot live installer is how it installer or repairs system, so just always boot in UEFI mode. Forget you even have a legacy setting and always boot flash drives in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials, a simple solution worked for me:

- reboot the system;
- enter BIOS setup;
- go to "Boot sequence";
- create a new boot option with path EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi;
- move this new option to first place;
- save and exit.