# Ubuntu fails to boot after Partition was moved | Superblock not found by GRUB

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, grub-efi

My current situation;

I have tried to shrink down `C:` and add the resulting space to my Ubuntu partition. I've done this using Windows (which was probably the biggest mistake) and in the process I moved the "unallocated" space from the end of `C:` to the beginning of the Ubuntu Partition (the one with filesystem Ext4).
[image: My current Situation]

Apparently Ubuntu does not boot anymore because the superblock is not found by GRUB. The partition is not mountable due to possible corruption on a live Ubuntu I bootet to. HELP

Question; **How can I repair GRUB on my Ubuntu 20.04?**

**Edit; [Boot Repair info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VzHSrrqFDh/)**

Comment: You show UEFI system & UEFI installs, but installed a BIOS boot version of grub?? And your ESP is not showing the Windows UEFI boot files/folder? You need a Windows repair/recovery flash drive to fix that. I might try fsck on all ext4 partitions and then reinstall of grub in UEFI mode. How you boot install or repair flash drive UEFI or BIOS for both Ubuntu & Windows is then how it repairs. So only boot in UEFI mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Then full reinstall of grub in UEFI boot mode using advanced mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who believes this?! I was successfully by running `fsck`
If you still can, only proceed with a **Backup**

1); **List your disks with**

```
sudo sfdisk -l
```

2); **Find the one with your boot on it**. In my case `/dev/nvme0n1p6` (could be `/dev/sdaX` for you)

```
Device      Start        End          Sectors      Size   Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    923647    921600   450M Windows-Recovery
/dev/nvme0n1p2    923648   1126399    202752    99M EFI-System
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1126400   1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4   1159168 817598519 816439352 389,3G Microsoft Basis
/dev/nvme0n1p5 817600512 818739199   1138688   556M Windows-Recovery
/dev/nvme0n1p6 818741248 974942207 156200960  74,5G Linux-Filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 974942208 974991359     49152    24M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p8 974993408 976771071   1777664   868M Windows-Recovery
```

3. **Use** `fsck` **to check for errors**

   sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6

use additional `-y` flag after 'sudo' to try fix all errors immediatly.

4. **try booting**

#### If you get something like;

```
Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 

filesystem....you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:

e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

(Backup first - also any other OS partition)

**You can try to**

```
e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda
```

**or**

```
e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-allocate the memory to its original state and then try to boot into Ubuntu. Should work.
Then Partition again using Gparted in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have already tried that. Sadly, this did not work. I just added some Boot Repair info

Comment: check out here: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-grub-cannot-boot-after-resizing-windows-xp-ntfs-partition-to-be-done-duplicate/