# Potential Hard Drive Failure on Ubuntu/Windows Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

I'm experiencing severe trouble with my Laptop, a ThinkPad P52s with dual booted Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.

I've been using Ubuntu almost exclusively for all work, and recently when doing typical tasks the computer froze and gave a black screen. It has occasionally done such things so I shut it down, and attempted a reboot. It put me into Ubuntu recovery mode, and there I reviewed the logs with `journalctl -xb`. I have extensive pictures, but most relevantly it says `timed out waiting for device dev-sdb1.device`, which is the name of my Ubuntu partition.
[image]

However, I can boot into Windows. There, it shows my linux partition as having 100% free space. I have tried 1) manually removing the battery 2) booting into recovery mode with different kernel versions (5.4.0-62, 5.4.0-60, 5.4.0-58, 5.0.0-29, 4.15.0-132) 3) copious reboots and restarts.
In fact, the Ubuntu recovery mode and GRUB has exhibited numerous graphical errors that has inhibited its functioning.
[image]
I made absolutely no edits to the system before it occured, and these facts lead me to believe it's a hardware issue. There had been minor system updates I had put off, but I have no reason to believe it is major. Absolutely any help or advice is appreciated, thank you.

Edit: I cannot run SmartStatus in GUI, and attempting `apt install smartmontools` returns the error `Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap`, along with a bunch of could not resolve/failed to fetch errors. I somehow Managed To Run `fschk` which returns `special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist` and some "linux image found" messages.

Edit 2: live booted in Ubuntu, SMART thinks the partition is healthy and e2fsck doesn't see any bad blocks.

Comment: About dead center of the picture of the error it says the hard drive has failed.  I agree with you hardware issue I think the hard drive has failed. But that is just me.

Comment: Does it make sense to have failed if I'm successfully running Windows on the same drive, albeit on a different partition?

Comment: Windows does not see Linux partitions, so that is normal. What does SmartStatus show? you can use Disks and icon in upper right corner or install the command line version into live installer. If passed not fail, then you may be able to run fsck. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789  or more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting

Comment: Yes it does not all the drive is bad just some of it. Happens all the time.

Comment: @oldfred, I've edited the above lost with more info. Basically, I can't install Smart status and it looks bad.

Comment: Are you running it from a live installer?  And then is it still sdb1? My flash drive usually becomes sda and every other drive moves up a letter.

Comment: not currently, I do not possess a bootable USB at the moment.

Comment: Successfully live booted, edited.