# No recommended repair option after running Boot Repair

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

Tried to do a Boot Repair but I wasn't getting the "Recommended Repair" option. The only option I have is to consult online forums. Here, is my pastebin link - https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/bgtJPTq8wk/

I don't understand most of it honestly. It would be great if I could get some help on this. In the pastebin link, this was the suggested repair was which doesn't look good to me as far as I understand.

```
Suggestedrepair:
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

Comment: */mnt/BootInfo/sda2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error* is probably all you need to know: The drive likely failed. Replace it. Boot Repair does not repair hardware, obviously.

Comment: Did you originally install with UEFI Secure boot on? Try with it off. And maybe a fsck on your sda2 partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: I tried Secure boot ON and OFF. Both gave me the same output.