# Ubuntu 20.04.1 Boot Repair Error

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

Having trouble booting up Ubuntu. The Grub appears on start up but it returns this error message when booting Ubuntu:

```
fra initranfs and switch to another root fs: chroot to NEW_ROOT, delete all in/, NEW-ROOT must be a mountpoint
```

I tried the Boot Repair Disk but it returned this error message at the end of the Boot Info Summary report:

```
sda1   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid e782db0a-566b-4b1c-ac14-163d062c1a12 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg


Error code 32
mount -r /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2

mount -r /dev/sda2 : Error code 32
Error code 32
mount -r /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2

mount -r /dev/sda2 : Error code 32


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

Any advice on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Post the link Boot-Repair creates to entire report. If necessary rerun it. You may need to run fsck on sda2 if that is ext4 / (root) partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789  and then run the full reinstall of grub & a new kernel from Boot-Repair's advanced mode.

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Dd6y83rz2H/

Comment: Configuration does look normal. Did you try the e2fsck on sda2?

Comment: Not yet. I'm somewhat of a newbie. How exactly do I do that? I can't access my dev/sda2 partition. Apparently it's no longer mounted. I tried a reinstall from DVD by using the "something else" option and specifying the sda2 mount as /. The last backup was taken 4 weeks ago and I would like to preserve the current files if possible. Unfortunatly, the re-install froze during the "saving files" process. It never got past that.

Comment: I figured out how and it worked! No need to re-install. :o) THANK YOU for your assistance!!

Comment: Best wishes to you for the coming year!