# Is my slow bootup related to dual booting Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, filesystem

I just sat down through an +11 minute of bootup! my machine is not old or slow (specs below) but the problem seems to be related to the filesystem, I have Ubuntu 20.04 on HDD and Windows 10 on SSD, I always got slow bootups because every time I boot I have to sit through "filesystem checks" but this time it was insane.

My specs:

```
           .-/+oossssoo+/-.               hasan@hasan-Nitro-AN515-43 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Nitro AN515-43 V1.10 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 20 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2557 (dpkg), 10 (flatpak), 17 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: fish 3.3.1 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Graphite-dark-nord 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Graphite-dark-nord [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Win11-dark [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3750H with Radeon Vega Mobile 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Picasso 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 3721MiB / 13922MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Results of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
11min 31.505s fstrim.service                                                             >
  3min 2.126s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                 >
      26.516s fwupd.service                                                              >
      24.551s dev-sda3.device                                                            >
      22.023s snapd.service                                                              >
      17.397s networkd-dispatcher.service                                                >
      15.977s systemd-journal-flush.service                                              >
      15.788s udisks2.service                                                            >
      13.858s plymouth-read-write.service                                                >
      12.843s accounts-daemon.service                                                    >
      11.252s libvirtd.service                                                           >
      10.285s dev-loop22.device                                                          >
      10.160s dev-loop15.device                                                          >
      10.083s dev-loop14.device                                                          >
      10.037s dev-loop24.device                                                          >
      10.012s dev-loop19.device                                                          >
       9.907s dev-loop18.device                                                          >
       9.855s dev-loop23.device                                                          >
       9.682s dev-loop20.device                                                          >
       9.660s dev-loop26.device                                                          >
       9.632s dev-loop9.device                                                           >
       9.565s dev-loop16.device                                                          >
       9.170s dev-loop1.device                                                           >
       9.164s dev-loop4.device                                                           >
       9.163s dev-loop13.device                                                          >
       9.156s dev-loop17.device                                                          >
       9.155s avahi-daemon.service                                                       >
       9.154s bluetooth.service                                                          >
       9.136s NetworkManager.service                                                     >
       8.928s dev-loop25.device                                                          >
       8.820s ModemManager.service                                                       >
       8.586s dev-loop11.device                                                          >
       8.471s polkit.service                                                             >
       8.210s dev-loop5.device                                                           >
       8.059s switcheroo-control.service                                                 >
       8.048s thermald.service                                                           >
       8.047s systemd-logind.service                                                     >
       8.044s systemd-machined.service                                                   >
       8.041s wpa_supplicant.service                                                     >
       7.868s dev-loop2.device                                                           >
       7.758s dev-loop21.device                                                          >
       7.555s dev-loop3.device                                                           >
       7.433s dev-loop10.device                                                          >
       7.290s dev-loop12.device                                                          >
       6.918s dev-loop8.device                                                           >
       6.891s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                             >
       6.462s dev-loop6.device                                                           >
       6.289s dev-loop7.device                                                           >
       5.125s systemd-resolved.service                                                   >
       4.758s gpu-manager.service                                                        >
       4.402s dev-loop0.device                                                           >
       4.363s zebra.service                                                              >
       3.592s apport.service                                                             >
       3.579s snapd.apparmor.service                                                     >
       3.505s rsyslog.service                                                            >
       3.472s tlp.service                                                                >
       3.347s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                             >
       3.334s systemd-udevd.service                                                      >
       2.927s snap-bare-5.mount                                                          >
       2.870s secureboot-db.service                                                      >
       2.713s apparmor.service                                                           >
       2.709s snap-code-85.mount                                                         >
       2.552s snap-code-86.mount                                                         >
       2.544s gdm.service                                                                >
       2.373s snap-core-11993.mount                                                      >
       2.354s user@125.service                                                           >
       2.335s ssh.service                                                                >
       2.276s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-90BC\x2dAD77.service                      >
       2.252s snap-core-12603.mount                                                      >
       2.190s grub-common.service                                                        >
       2.131s colord.service                                                             >
       2.041s snap-core18-2253.mount                                                     >
       1.983s snap-core18-2284.mount                                                     >
       1.857s upower.service                                                             >
       1.763s e2scrub_reap.service                                                       >
       1.762s lm-sensors.service                                                         >
       1.702s snap-core20-1270.mount                                                     >
       1.680s snap-core20-1328.mount
```

**My question:**

How should I debug this problem?

Comment: What is the SMART status of your HDD? [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) explains how to check it. If your HDD is really old (or if SMART says it's failing), then replacing the HDD might fix it.

Comment: Some settings to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Not sure I have seen where trim should take a long time. Have ;you manually run fsck? http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting  & have you manually run trim to see if any errors? It should only auto run trim once per week.What does this show? systemctl status fstrim.timer

Comment: @cocomac SMART says disk is OK, I am following the other suggestions might I find the cause of the problem