# Grub2 re-installation failed with boot-repair

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I have a MSI mother board and a SSD drive for dual system booting.

It worked fine until suddenly it showed cannot find memory block on hd2 or something like that. I didn't pay attention and rebooted the PC. Then I could only access Windows system. I rebooted again, then I couldn't access either.

I prepared a boot-repair usb drive, and auto-repaired it. But it shows

error: no such device: XXXXXXXXXXX.

Then, it entered rescue mode.

I tried `ls`

it shows  `(hd0)(hd1)(hd2)`

then I tried `ls (hd0)/`, `ls (hd1)/` and `ls (hd2)/`

the results are all `Filesystem is unknown`

Here is the pastebin log https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NfhrtD5bXx/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems the drive is failing.

Comment: If smartdata https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools says drive is ok, you may just need fsck. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Also if Ubuntu, you have Disks and in upper right corner hamburger icon is smart tools.

Comment: Thank you! I will let you know the results.

Comment: The smartmontools shows no problems. the e2fcsk -C0 -p -v -f /dev/sdd1 and the other partitions on my SSD doesn't repair  because they are not ext2/ext3/ext4. <http://codepad.org/HQJy3jyd>