# System enters GRUB menu after Windows 11 update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I'm using an Asus ROG Strix system, and I've been dual-booting Windows and Linux for a couple of months now with no issue. A few days ago, I decided to upgrade my system to Windows 11. After the update, I'm stuck with a GRUB menu saying something like

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04...  
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. 
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.  
grub>
```

I've checked a couple of other questions online like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) and most were recommended booting using a live USB stick and fixing the bootloader using the `boot-repair` package. I installed the package but I don't have the option most people see and recommend. The `recommended repair` option. [This](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8PX2K8H795/) is the pastebin from creating the BootInfo summary option. Not sure where to go from here. Wondering how I can repair the bootloader to what it was before.

I am also unable to even go past the first step in [this](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) tutorial, as I always get an error `mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.` Looking further into this, I tried to fix the bad drive using `fsck` as outline [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315063/mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock) but then I get this error.

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Also, any of the recommended commands give the same error as well. Running the `sudo fdisk -l` command, and I get this on my main drive with `/dev/sdb5` being my Ubuntu partition

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 256.18 GiB, 275064201216 bytes, 537234768 sectors
Disk model: Crucial_CT275MX3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EF9C52D6-8EB4-46F7-89FA-4AEA30C7089D

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1085439   1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2    1085440   1290239    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3    1290240   1323007     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4    1323008 319723994 318400987 151.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  321163264 537233407 216070144   103G Linux filesystem
```

Not sure it matters, but I eventually downgraded back to Windows 10 from 11 (for personal reasons) but that obviously had no effect on the issue.

Comment: Did you run e2fsck or fsck on sdb5? Not a drive? https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Best to also show command you used, not just results.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't add commands, but I ran all those. Specifically these commands `e2fsck -b 8193 <device>` and `e2fsck -b 32768 <device>` and they both gave the same error as when I used the `fsck` command. However I'll try the ones in the link and let you know if they work

Answer (score 0):

Edit your BIOS to run ubuntu first

Remember to update your grub after you edit it

See if you can maybe boot into the safe-mode for ubuntu and try a repair there

It might also be that the bootable drive was dirty or the port it was plugged into was faulty

Try a reinstall of Ubuntu if nothing else happens. Format the partition you're trying to install Ubuntu on. You can use basic formatter option Ubuntu installer provides, or you can use something like TestDisk to wipe it clean

Comment: Thanks, however, I've already set Ubuntu to run first, but that isn't the problem. Also, I'm trying to look if there's a way to recover the partition without losing my data. Wiping the partition is currently a last resort