# Stuck at grub - After resized partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gparted, grubrescue

Here's what happened -

I am seeing grub> when I boot (NOT grub rescue)

I have a dual boot computer,
To summarise, I was running out of space in ubuntu but my windows had abundance of space, I previously went to windows 10 disk management and "shrink partition" from there.
I extended my partition twice previously, but last time I shrank partition, I shrank the maximum amount of space I was allowed by windows 10.
and added it to Ubuntu.
Windows won't let me shrink more,
this time i used a bootable drive and ran gparted and sheank windows 10 by 25 gbs and added it right into Ubuntu.
and then I thought i was done.
And I rebooted and operating system selection did show up
AND I SELECTED WINDOWS 10 not Ubuntu, because I had some stuff to do in windows.
And when I logged into windows (typed password) a black screen appeared and I forcefully shut down my laptop by holding power key for few seconds. then when I booted again It showed grub> and If i select windows from boot menu (ctrl+f12 something, in my laptop i got a button to open bios etc.) I see the default windows 10 troubleshooting window. (that blue window)

Idk what happened, but when I now check my Ubuntu system from a bootable live Ubuntu, I see nothing at /dev/sda5

and when I type the command -

ls (hd0,gpt5)

it prints -
Partition hd0,gpt5: Filesystem type ext* - Last modification time 2022-06-03 14:05:31 Friday, UUID <some_uuid> - Partition start at 120710144KiB - Total size 113189888KiB

(I am sure beyond anything /dev/sda5 is my ubuntu partition)

and when I type

ls (hd0,gpt5)/

It prints nothing

Comment: Only use Windows tools to edit NTFS partiitons and only use Linux tools like gparted for editing Linux partitions. Boot-Repair cannot fix Windows, you may need a Windows repair flash drive or possibly boot into repair console and make repairs. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  &          
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xyRtwb924b/

Comment: I am not in much need of windows, I can sacrifice it to make Ubuntu run.

Comment: You have UEFI system, with UEFI installs. But also have BIOS boot loader in MBR. Did you attempt Windows repairs when booted in BIOS mode. Just never boot in BIOS mode. You should be able to boot both Windows & Ubuntu directly from UEFI boot menu. Report did not show fstab, so may of had issues mounting it. I might try fsck or e2fsck on sda5. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: Yes i attempt windows repairs, but when I now go to windows troubleshooting window (blue window with options to repair system, advanced options) and when I try to open uefi from there it restarts and the bios is opened (the one which one has to navigate with keyboard).

Comment: I have ran the fsck command and now I have a folder in the partition called lost+found, and I don't seem to be able to explore the partition with nautilus

Comment: If it takes more than an hour to repair, it typically is better just to reinstall & restore from your backups. You do have backups? If not: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery I have used photorec and it takes a long time and only recovers files by type, not full file name.

Comment: I was not able to repair, I am sure there was a way, but rather I used `ext4magic` to recovery my data, and I recovered almost all my data. and thanks for the advice and help! It really helped! thanks!