# GNU Grub error page whenever I boot : Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported

Tags: boot, grub-efi

I am a new Linux user. I am facing problem in booting my PC when I installed Ubuntu 20.4 along with Windows10 dual boot.
Now when I start my PC there is GNU Grub page opens with this message: `Minimal BASH-like line editing supported`.

I have already tried Boot-Repair through a live USB, but it did not opened the Boot-Repair option for my PC, therefore I couldn't my grub this way. I am also providing the Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary here for your reference.

[image]

Boot Info Summary:

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Intel Corporation GP107M [GeForce MX350] from Intel Corporation NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: V1.21(1.21) from Insyde Corp.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - SecureBoot disabled - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Linpus lite   HD(1,GPT,76ec9201-75cb-4f85-ae26-69a3862594f3,0x800,0x1d4b7df)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,ec5d527e-dc5a-4fda-aafa-917b848989d5,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...t................
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,ec5d527e-dc5a-4fda-aafa-917b848989d5,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
85fa9d77b929ec4231aba29476574eb6   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
fa1bf1a7f90a852abe0bdbd089b7f1b0   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
72293f4ecf0f5b24dce601d2c3c4b26e   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
75641ea3cae97c7ea935e501d6e5e227   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.96 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: D5D6027D-CDF5-4082-AE26-52FF17C716A6
              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    239616  313628475 313388860 149.4G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 999170048 1000212479   1042432   509M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 313628672  999170047 685541376 326.9G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 14.66 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Disk identifier: 434AF692-7A93-470A-A868-3D6A7EFB59EA
      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1   2048 30719966 30717919 14.7G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:15.7GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Flash USB Disk:;
1:1049kB:15.7GB:15.7GB:fat32:Main Data Partition:msftdata;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:KINGSTON RBUSNS8154P3512GJ1:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:161GB:160GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:161GB:512GB:351GB:::;
4:512GB:512GB:534MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      vfat     2AAE-67F3                            76ec9201-75cb-4f85-ae26-69a3862594f3 UBUNTU 20_0 Main Data Partition
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     4EF5-D603                            ec5d527e-dc5a-4fda-aafa-917b848989d5             EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               0888de48-53f2-4058-a05e-2d203b8eae9a             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     DC66F65666F630BE                     db0fe195-8412-4db8-b315-2e5815c5ccd2             Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     76C038E3C038AAEF                     87653757-d53a-4d05-8e62-934625b3775e             
└─nvme0n1p5                                               ff8a1458-4da2-405f-88f5-9a90f31122e8             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail            Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1          65.9M             31% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3         438.6G 47089725675845% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4          88.3M             83% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/sda1               11.5G             22% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3         fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4         fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 508bd216-1108-4a5b-acef-710a0205374f root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sda1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sda

00000000  41 4b 45 4f fc 31 c0 fa  8e d0 bc 00 7c fb 8e d8  |AKEO.1......|...|
00000010  bb 13 04 8b 07 83 e8 04  89 07 c1 e0 06 8e c0 b7  |................|
00000020  07 b8 7f 00 cd 10 31 db  31 c9 ba 4f 18 b8 00 06  |......1.1..O....|
00000030  cd 10 31 d2 b4 02 cd 10  b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13 72  |..1......A..U..r|
00000040  27 81 fb 55 aa 75 21 f7  c1 01 00 74 1b 66 31 c0  |'..U.u!....t.f1.|
00000050  66 50 6a 22 06 66 50 6a  08 6a 10 89 e6 b4 42 cd  |fPj".fPj.j....B.|
00000060  13 9f 83 c4 10 9e eb 0d  b8 08 02 b9 23 00 ba 80  |............#...|
00000070  00 31 db cd 13 bb 07 00  72 0b 31 f6 8c c0 8e d8  |.1......r.1.....|
00000080  e8 3f 00 eb 06 be 17 7d  e8 37 00 31 c0 8e d8 be  |.?.....}.7.1....|
00000090  63 7d e8 2d 00 e8 1d 00  b4 01 cd 16 75 08 b4 02  |c}.-........u...|
000000a0  cd 16 24 04 74 f2 31 c0  8e d8 b8 34 12 a3 73 04  |..$.t.1....4..s.|
000000b0  ea 00 00 ff ff b4 01 cd  16 74 06 b4 00 cd 16 e2  |.........t......|
000000c0  f4 c3 ac 3c 00 74 4f 3c  0d 74 f7 3c 0a 75 10 53  |...<.tO<.t.<.u.S|
000000d0  b4 03 cd 10 fe c6 b2 00  b4 02 cd 10 5b eb e3 3c  |............[..<|
000000e0  5c 75 1c b1 02 ac 3c 46  7f d8 2c 30 3c 09 7e 02  |\u....<F..,0<.~.|
000000f0  2c 07 c0 e3 04 24 0f 08  c3 fe c9 75 e8 eb c3 b9  |,....$.....u....|
00000100  01 00 b4 09 cd 10 53 31  db b4 03 cd 10 fe c2 b4  |......S1........|
00000110  02 cd 10 5b eb ac c3 0d  0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |...[.....       |
00000120  20 20 20 20 20 20 5c 30  34 2a 2a 2a 20 45 52 52  |      \04*** ERR|
00000130  4f 52 3a 20 54 48 49 53  20 4d 45 44 49 41 20 43  |OR: THIS MEDIA C|
00000140  41 4e 4e 4f 54 20 42 4f  4f 54 20 49 4e 20 4c 45  |ANNOT BOOT IN LE|
00000150  47 41 43 59 20 4d 4f 44  45 20 2a 2a 2a 5c 30 37  |GACY MODE ***\07|
00000160  0d 0a 00 0d 0a 0d 0a 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.......         |
00000170  20 20 20 20 5c 37 30 50  6c 65 61 73 65 20 72 65  |    \70Please re|
00000180  6d 6f 76 65 20 74 68 69  73 20 6d 65 64 69 61 20  |move this media |
00000190  61 6e 64 20 70 72 65 73  73 20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65  |and press any ke|
000001a0  79 20 74 6f 20 72 65 62  6f 6f 74 5c 30 37 00 00  |y to reboot\07..|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  02 00 ee fe ff 77 01 00  00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00  |.....w..........|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200




Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix
```

Comment: That's not an error message, it simply tells you that the keyboard interface is similar to that in Bash.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Yes the information is from the boot repair.
I have also added the error page screen shot for your reference. Please have a look.

Comment: Default boot is 0000 per `sudo efibootmgr -v` which is also shown in report. But your p5 partition is not fully shown. I might try fsck or e2fsck on it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 If fsck works, then Boot-Repair or just changing boot order with efibootmgr may work.