# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS boot problem

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd

Today my computer with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS stopped working and goes straight into BIOS. Boot drive is no longer shown in the BIOS and it looks like that GPT partition table information is gone.
I put SSD into enclosure and loaded live Ubuntu CD from Ventoy USB (https://www.ventoy.net).
Then I run Boot Repair tool, tool report is available at this link: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dhGrzkgqMk/.

I did not proceed with any repairs from Boot Repair Tool, when I tried to access Ubuntu partitions on SSD from live CD I got error: `can't read superblock on /dev/sdxx`.

The SSD is Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1Tb in size.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/nvme0n1p4  
/dev/nvme0n1p4: recovering journal  
/dev/nvme0n1p4: Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.  
/dev/nvme0n1p4: Run journal anyway  
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.  
(i.e., without -a or -p options)  
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -C0 -f -v /dev/nvme0n1p4  
/dev/nvme0n1p4: recovering journal  
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.  
Run journal anyway<y>? yes  
e2fsck: Input/output error while recovering journal of /dev/nvme0n1p4  
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/nvme0n1p4  
/dev/nvme0n1p4: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********  


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/nvme0n1p5  
/dev/nvme0n1p5: Error writing file system info: Input/output error               


/dev/nvme0n1p5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.  
    (i.e., without -a or -p options)  
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -C0 -f -v /dev/nvme0n1p5  
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)  
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes  
Pass 2: Checking directory structure                                             
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity                                          
Pass 4: Checking reference counts  
Pass 5: Checking group summary information                                       
Error writing file system info: Input/output error                               

/dev/nvme0n1p5: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****  

buntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/nvme0n1p4  
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)  
/dev/nvme0n1p4: recovering journal  
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.  
Run journal anyway? yes  

e2fsck: Input/output error while recovering journal of /dev/nvme0n1p4  
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/nvme0n1p4  


/dev/nvme0n1p4: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********  

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/nvme0n1p5  
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)  
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes  
Pass 2: Checking directory structure  
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity  
Pass 4: Checking reference counts  
Pass 5: Checking group summary information  
Error writing file system info: Input/output error  

/dev/nvme0n1p5: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
```

I have full Veeam backup from about 2 months ago before I upgraded to 22.04 LTS. Is there any way that I could restore my current data from those two damaged partitions?

Comment: It stopped before I put it into enclosure. That computer has no monitor or keyboard attached so I used enclosure to test SSD on my laptop.

Comment: I didn't proceed with boot repair as I don't have much Ubuntu experience and I was worry that I might create more damage so I decided to ask question first as I can always run Boot Repair tool .

Comment: Its not able to mount p4 nor anything related to p5. I might try fsck or e2fsck on all ext4 partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Do command twice with the different parameters. And for all ext4 partitions.

Comment: I'll try that and report results. Thank you.