# How can I get rid off fork bomb?

Tags: bash

I tried the fork bomb code :

```
:(){:|:&};:
```

and closed the PuTTy. Now it is not accepting the new connections(Denial of Service attack).

How can I recover from that ?

Comment: Which code exactly?

Comment: This one   :(){:|:&};:

Comment: Is there any possibity of data delete ?

Comment: Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Defusing) : `while (sleep 100 &) do; done` (I didn't test it so I won't post it as an answer, but it might still be relevant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to hard reboot the computer.

Assuming you have console access, you might try to get the process group ID (PGID) and kill that with :

```
kill -- -PGID
```

Or use `SIGKILL` instead of `SIGTERM` :

```
kill -9 -- -PGID
```

but it might not be possible to get the PGID practically as the system might be already occupied by the forked processes creating a deadlock.

This deadlock can happen when you don't have a sufficient limit on the number of processes a user or group can own, **so it's better to set a lower limit before trying something destructive like a fork-bomb.**

Comment: Reeboot? sounds like Windows :P =)

Comment: @A.B. Possibly..it is the last resort..

Comment: that's my first upvote for a "reboot answer" and I hope, it's the last one =)

Comment: @A.B. Yeah..we all wish..

Comment: @heemayl is there any chance if I am using it on Virtual box ? Is there any way out ?

Comment: @PareshZawar Can you login to virtualbox directly ?

Comment: @heemayl yes I can login to virtual box

Comment: @PareshZawar Great..now try `ps -eo pid,ppid,pgid,cmd | grep ':'` and check whats the output..you would get the PID,PPID and PGID of `:`..

Comment: @heemayl if I restart forcefully then ?

Comment: @PareshZawar That would always work but thats the last resort..

Comment: @heemayl Is there any risk or damage of data in force restart /

Comment: @PareshZawar yes..there is..but you should try `REISUB` sequence..read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: `REISUB` is actually `SUB` (or possibly `SUO`) only, depends on the binary digits defined by the setting in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf` - ref: http://askubuntu.com/a/334292/289138

Answer (score 5):

You have used the classic "fork bomb" to use up all of your system's processes, and now your cannot get the system to run a process to help you (and all commands, programs, etc. require a process to run "in"). Any intervention will have to come from outside the system (e.g.,reset the VM, cycle the power, CtrlAltDelete). Did you not understand what then code says?

```
:(){:|:&};:

:()
```

Define a shell function, called ":".

```
   {
```

Begin the definition of the function, which is:

```
      :
```

Call the ":" function.

```
       |
```

Pipe the output of ":"

```
        :
```

to another call to ":"

```
         &
```

Fork a process to put the pipeline (`:|:`) in the background.

```
          }
```

End of definition of the function ":"

```
           ;
```

End of the shell statement defining the ":" function

```
            :
```

Call the ":" function to begin.

If you run code without understanding it, you accept the results of the code.

Comment: While an explanation of what the code does is interesting, it doesn't quite explain how to stop it, which is what the question asks. Could you perhaps expand on that outside intervention sentence?

Comment: @8bittree: I did. "(e.g.,reset the VM, cycle the power, CtrlAltDelete)"

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/435917/) it should in theory be possible to use [Alt+SysRq+f](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) to get rid of fork bombs — although, again, probably only possible if the kernel is capable of allocating enough memory to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

If you **can't** connect again, you do not have a chance. Maybe you can wait for an `out of memory error`

If you **can** connect, try the command below

```
pkill -f :
```

---

And as you said in your comments

> I am running it in Virtual box

Reset the machine via VirtualBox.

Comment: I am running it in Virtual box. So is there any chance ?

Comment: Sure, shutdown the machine via VirtualBox