# Do the key combinations for ubuntu change for a laptop keyboard?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, freeze

- I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>REISUB</kbd> and that never works so I must hold down power button to force power down.
- Also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> with no change.

On my Dell Latitude E6500 the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key is shared with a function key which requires the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to also be pressed.

Is this the reason it doesn't work for me? Can someone give the key combinations for a laptop keyboard?

Comment: SysRq is disabled by default. Have you confirmed it is enabled? If I remember correctly, the Ctrl+Alt+ Backspace functionality has been removed entirely.

Comment: If this is the case, how do I enable the sysrq key? I will start another question because I don't find anyone answering that question either.

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/q/11002/301745