# Install Ubuntu on unbootable Acer Aspire E5-575 "Default Boot Device Missing or Failed."

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, acer

Many tries - many errors, much searching, remain clueless...
Acer Aspire E5-575 (I can use F2 to get into the BIOS)
Trying to:
**Install Ubuntu Zesty Zapus 17.04 from USB**
continually get error:
**Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed.**
after "successful" installation
I can run Ubuntu from the USB and have started Gparted and get this:
**The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.**
Potential problem may be from this observation:
I pulled out the flash drive just as the re-boot started and got all sorts of errors (about 15-20) the first of which says:

```
[     0.218737]  platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1
```

further errors indicate it's trying to read sda where the OS was installed on `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: Did you find any of the many threads on Acer (all models) and its unique UEFI requirement of setting "trust" on grub/shim .efi boot files. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291335&p=13341757#post13341757 But Ubuntu's grub only installs to the ESP - efi system partition on sda. So make sure you have that. If external USB drive, it is more complicated.

Comment: I found many threads - not specifically the ones oldfred put up partially because I'm not trying (right now) to dual boot - just get it to boot to 17.04.  The first link, I think, involves the granting of authority during boot and my notes indicate the following:"Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" is available
  HDD0  (enter>
  <EFI>  (enter)
  <ubuntu> (enter)
   enabled 5 files for booting (by using "Yes" mixed case as the above page suggests)
    fwupx64.efi
    grubx64.efi
    shimx64.efi
    mmx64.efi
    fbx64.efi

Comment: The shim.efi you mentioned might be covered (above comment) by the shimx64.efi I think I gave permission to previously.  I'm new posting and appreciate your help

Comment: Looking over oldfred's suggestions again I see "only installs to the ESP - efi system partition on sda" whereas my booting to my flash drive with Ubuntu comes up with the flash as sda and the hard drive as sdb.  How do I make the hard drive sda?  Maybe try booting from DVD and use Gparted?

Comment: I never had flash drive as sda, but have seen a few others. But have had my sdb become sdc and flash drive sdb. And found that was becuase I had skipped a SATA port. So is your hard drive in SATA0, not SATA1? If all of boot files installed back into flash drive, does flash drive now have /EFI/ubuntu folder? You may be able to copy all of that back to hard drive's ESP and edit fstab to have correct UUID of hard drive's ESP, not that of flash drive. May also need efibootmgr to add entry to UEFI menu.

Comment: I see SCSI but no reference to SATA (which I thought to be mutually exclusive).  I created a DVD and booted to it:  start GParted:
  now it has /dev/sda as the drive up on the top right of the gui window (931.51 GiB) (which is about what the terabyte drive is supposed to be) but below in the partition table:
  * /dev/sda1   EFI System Partition  fat32  512.00 MiB  4.46 MiB (used)  Flags: boot, esp
  * /dev/sda2            ext4   931.01 GiB
With the drive looking different (no sdb entries), try install again
clicked on gui icon "install Ubuntu 17.04"

Comment: Two error windows which I went through before continuing the install:  Force UEFI Installation?  (window title)
This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode".  If you continut to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the maching into any BIOS-mide operating systems later

Comment: If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that here.  If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you shoud choose NOT to force UEFI installation here.
  "Go Back"  "Continue in UEFI mode"  NOT WORKING - GETTING SQUASHFS errors on DOS type screen -

Comment: Use the ppa and add it to your Ubuntu installer and be sure to boot in UEFI mode. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred I managed to perform the boot info stuff on the link you so thoughtfully provided but couldn't get the standard upload of the report to work so I stuck it here: (http://siltontennis.com/boot-record.txt).  Soon I have to go to my real job (this stuff is just my phoney job)  THANKS

Comment: Do not know LVM. But yours is first I have seen without a separate /boot partition. Perhaps because most are also encrypted. Boot-Repair has troubles telling RAID from LVM as both use /dev/mapper. But you told it that it is RAID? "Is there RAID on this computer? yes" Someone that really knows LVM should be the one to help. Is there some specific reason for LVM? Those that use it are usually advanced users who do like it, but it adds additional complexity as you cannot use standard partition tools like gparted, but have to use LVM tools.

Comment: The only reason I chose LVM was because it's supposedly easier to partition later.  I think I can skip it at this point.  Latest install I did say RAID yes although I believe this is only for disk arrays - seemed to think it was RAID anyway so I tried it that way.  I think maybe I'll skip the LVM and try the install again.  I can use the link you provided.  @oldfred - thanks!!!

Comment: Paste from boot-repair at Sat, 26 Aug 2017 11:18:38 +0000
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25396342/

Comment: Boot-Repair tried to run fsck. I suggest you run it like this example but with your sda2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 You may also want to turn off UEFI secure boot.

Comment: started Gparted which reports:
/dev/sda 14.77 GiB   (I believe the 16 gig flash drive)
  unallocated Partition and file system
/dev/sdb 931.01 GiB (I believe to be the system hard drive)
  /dev/sdb1  EFI System Partition  FAT32   512MiB    4.46MiB used
  /dev/sdb2  "                            "  ext4    931GiB   21.28 GiB used
<ctl><alt>T

Comment: sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sdb2
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
seemed to run just fine and provided info:

183628 inodes used (0.30%, out of 61022208)
  (15 lines of info)
------------------
183619 files
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed.
Insert Recovery...
Then Select 'Boot Manager' to choose...-> Disable Secure Boot (under [UEFI])2017/08/28 - 08:55 still waiting for system battery to run out of power so I can reboot.  Again thanks for your help @oldfred

Comment: Did you run both command, even if no errors on first command? You should be able to shutdown. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power And: http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006

Comment: I was able to shutdown (battery ran out), am getting nowhere, and now: "Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed."
next screen:
dbgrubx64
dbfsupx
dbshimx64
dbmmxefi
dbfbx64

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Boot Repair Disk:
Recommended repair doesn't work
Boot Repair Report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25483407/

Comment: Still shows errors on sda2. If you ran the e2fsck on sda2 then something major is wrong. Perhaps check in Disks on icon in upper right corner is Smart Status. While it can run tests all I know is if it reports drive is good or bad.

Answer (score 2):

- We made many Ubuntu installs, which failed to boot.
- Finally, in BIOS we did "Security > Restore Secure Boot to Factory Default". We reinstalled Ubuntu; it still failed to boot. Then in BIOS, "Security > Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing", we kept on HDD0, selected , and set "grubx64.efi" , "Wish to add this file?" to YES. [F10] Save and Exit. THAT booted up into Ubuntu (17.04). NO reinstall was required.