# Ubuntu 16 not booting

Tags: 16.04, boot, mount

I've been using Ubuntu 16 and yesterday it was taking too much time to boot.
So I forced restart it by pressing and holding the power button.
Later when I tried to boot it,it's "Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
How can I fix this without losing my data?

[image]

Comment: Yes i'am able to.
I can see 4 options : 
1.Ubuntu
2.Advanced options for Ubuntu
3.Memory Test (memtest+86+)
4.Memory Test (memtest+86+, serial console 115200)

Comment: second kernel is **Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-101-generic (upstart)** .

Comment: Try the one that says recovery mode. But forcing shutdown can cause other issues where you need fsck to get back to original issue. Never force shutdown, use REISUB. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power

Comment: @Videonauth selected **upstart** mode

Comment: @oldfred will try recovery after upstart .

Comment: @Videonauth how do i make sure, which is correct kernel version?

Comment: I selected both **upstart** and **recovery** mode,in both cases it is redirecting me to the same situation i showed in the pic above.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a live USB/CD, choose 'Try Ubuntu' and open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

1. List your partitions with `sudo fdisk -l` and choose the right one to mount:

   ```bsh
   sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
   ```

   Where `sdX` is your Ubuntu installation on your HDD. If you have an EFI boot system you need to mount your EFI partition as well.

   ```bsh
   sudo mount /dev/sdY /mnt/boot/efi
   ```

   Where `sdY` is your EFI partition.
2. Now mount the following and chroot into your install

   ```bsh
   # in case you need to reinstall the kernel (you will need LAN connection for this)
   sudo cp /mnt/etc/hosts /mnt/etc/hosts.old
   sudo cp /etc/hosts /mnt/etc/hosts
   sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf

   # the below is always needed
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
   sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys
   sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
3. Create a `update-initramfs` and `update-grub`. Make sure you put the right version number into the next line, you can find this by `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`.

   ```bsh
   update-initramfs -u -k 4.4.0-101-generic
   update-grub
   ```

   If that step fails for whatever reason you might want to reinstall that kernel with:

   ```bsh
    apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic linux-firmware
   ```
4. Unmount and reboot your system.

   ```bsh
   exit
   sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
   sudo umount /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo umount /mnt/sys
   sudo umount /mnt/proc
   sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi
   sudo umount /mnt
   reboot
   ```