# 18.04 black screen during install

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, 18.04, asus, nomodeset

I have an Asus FD503vx with GTX1050 Nvidia. I am trying to install 18.04 from  USB. 
I can get to the install Ubuntu screen, i edit it and add nomodeset ( i have tried every variation with order and even removing splash and quiet), still as it is loading the screen goes dark. I can here the Ubuntu sound like it is ready to go but cannot see anything. Are there any other tricks?

Update: so my BIOS is a newer style BIOS and i am not sure that i have secure boot turned off, how do i do this? I also found something that stated to use AHCI and turn on CMS but CMS is not active for me to select in the BIOS. Any tips.

Update: Found secure boot (on security page, just had to scroll down).

Comment: Secure Boot may be called Windows or "Other". Fine print often then says use "Other" setting if installing Windows 7 as Windows 7 does not support Secure Boot. You still want UEFI on, but BIOS/Legacy/CSM off for UEFI boot. You do not see CSM if Secure boot on as UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, system is either one or the other. You do need AHCI. Many Asus need pci=nomsi in addition to nomodeset if nVidia. Problems Installing on ASUS F555U   needed boot option pci=nomsi
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303665

Comment: Thank you the pci=nomso did the trick. the screen was very faint but i was able to read enough for the install. Everything working now. I have never had luck with the Nvidia installs. any thoughts, do i just leave well enough alone or try the additional software install, it suggested 390. Also the mouse is very touchy any tip for that?

Comment: next problem, mouse will freeze, i installed the synatics but no improvement, also the shutown screen buttons do not shut it down, i have to hard power down each time, any suggestions?,

Comment: Do use power switch to shutdown unless alt-prtsc RESIUB does not work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power  Otherwise post each issue as separate question.