# something is awfully wrong with my laptop and I have no idea what

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, ssd, startup

I've fairly recently begun to use Linux and am preferring it to windows a lot (terminal is awesome). Started off with mint which ran very smoothly but then transitioned into Ubuntu. It was working all fine until I finally decided to upgrade my HDD to an SSD. (I had issues with it) I installed the latest Ubuntu on a new SSD and for about a day it worked perfectly. However it began to operate really sluggish and eventually opening Firefox finally froze/bricked my laptop. With no other options I held down the power button and am now consistently greeted with errors that basically stating that my SSD doesn't exist and it can't boot as there's no boot option. Even trying to use a bootable USB and attempting to reinstall it doesn't recognise there's an SSD there. I re-tried my old HDD and same result (expected it was dying), however using other laptop HDD gathered over the years I managed to successfully boot into windows 7 on 2 different HDD.

Very rarely my laptop can boot successfully (with the ssd, haven't bothered with original HDD) but it eventually freezes up from doing simple things such as web browsing.

When shutting down with my SSD installed I occasionally see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/fey5a.jpg then followed by https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl6aH.jpg . I have also seen this screen once; https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaNJ1.jpg when I start up/shutdown(not with terminal) then followed by a lot of;

"system-journald[263]: fail to write entry" the number is always the same not sure if it means anything.

Is possible that I have a faulty SSD? As I could use other HDDs that I know are fine hence ruling out any possible faulty sata mounts? I've managed to get on somehow but I know shutting it down will kill it again for who know how long so are there any tests I can do to find out more about whats wrong? Already tried smartmontools and apparently all is good...

Nothing important was lost as it's all been backed up to an external HD. Would greatly appreciate any and all help available thanks

Comment: In Disks and icon in upper right corner is Smart Status. Does it say drive is good or bad? It also can run tests, but do not know about them or what really applies to SSD. Have you run trim? Did you full allocated SSD, or leave 10% available? Is drive getting full? Post these: `sudo parted -l`, `df -h` and `lsblk -f`.

Comment: well it says that its "ok" in disks, running trim using "sudo fstrim -v / " resulted in:
"/: 563.4 MiB (590716928 bytes) trimmed"

Comment: @oldfred I allocated all of the SSD for linux, no dual boot or anything like that and drive is nowhere near full just got it 2 days ago the command: https://imgur.com/gallery/pkWa3eZ and https://imgur.com/gallery/dkROIdy the first command didnt really work for me not sure if i typed it wrong or something

Comment: Do not use power button unless nothing else works. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power When it starts to slow, run top to see what is running. May not be drive, but run-away process. What brand/model system, some need boot parameters.

Comment: "do not use power button" yikes, I've remapped it to sleep now and it might have been abused many many times as its been bricking itself regularly. Its an asus x541sa-xx120t, I can't seem to find any bios updates for my specific model, found a slightly different model, considering flashing the bios with that slightly different model as my last resort.

Comment: I would not use another model's UEFI, even though brands often use very similar UEFI across many models. Forced shutdown often corrupts files, then with Windows you have to run chkdsk or if Ubuntu and ext4 run e2fsck to repair file system. Similar system: Asus X541UV [SOLVED] How to partition my ssd in order to install ubuntu 17.10 / 16.04.4
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392861