# Booting problem after force shutdown

Tags: boot

My laptop model is HP ProBook 440 GL. My Ubuntu got hanged while I was editing stuffs in gravity designer. And forcefully shut the system by pressing power button for long time. Now whenever I open my system it shows me three options to choose from.

1. Ubuntu
2. Advanced options for Ubuntu
3. System setup.

Whenever I click on the above two options and any following options in them (in option 2), the screen shows the pattern without any text in it and get stuck over there.

I have important data and more importantly some works to do. How do I get out of this issue?

Comment: Can you share the picture of that pattern? That might be helpful.

Comment: Best to never force shutdown unless only thing left. Use this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power And if any data is important, you must have good backups. Hard drives do totally fail, just not as often as they used to, so users become complacent.  Often forced shutdown corrupts file system and you need to run fsck on all ext4 partitions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789