# Freezing issue after installing SSD

Tags: 16.04, ssd, freeze, ubuntu-gnome

I recently installed a 240 GB Kingston M.2 SSD and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. But after working on it for a while it randomly freezes for a very long time even the mouse didn't work then. What should I do in this situation?

```
hp@hp-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        970M        5.4G        341M        1.4G        6.2G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
hp@hp-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=10026a97-9791-4a55-944b-e9141b8e1393 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=DA35-0453  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=820342c5-9b51-4e0d-a1df-d01ff6016cbb none            swap    sw              0       0
hp@hp-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$
```

Comment: Does it unfreeze by itself or do you need to reboot?  How much ram do you have and what cpu?

Comment: I need to reboot. I have 8 GB RAM and Intel i5 8th gen cpu

Comment: Have you tried the 'REISUB' keys to shutdown or you need to use power button and do a hard shutdown, also do you know what GPU you are using?

Comment: I used power button for shutting down. I don't know which you I'm using

Comment: you - gpu* autocorrect sucks!

Comment: Did you use ubuntu before on this computer, and if you did, it did not freeze up.  Doubt if it is the ssd, unless the connection is not tight.  There are some people having similar problems, so a google search with intel i5 and ubuntu 16.04 freezing might help.

Comment: Check for a firmware update for the SSD. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `cat /etc/fstab` and I'll take a look.

Comment: @heynnema I've edited the question.

Comment: Info on REISUB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power Have you updaded UEFI for your system? You also should add noatime parameter to ext4 partition mounts in fstab.  Like this for /  `noatime,errors=remount-ro`. When locked can you get to a terminal (alt f2) to see what is running with `top` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check the firmware on the new 240GB Kingston M.2 SSD.

Firmware and utility:

https://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/downloads?product=SA1000M8&filename=E8FK11L

Release notes:

https://media.kingston.com/support/downloads/A1000_E8FK11.L_RN.pdf