# Emergency mode Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: boot, reboot

Yesternight, my pc lagged, and I did a hard poweroff. After that I could not enter the system.
WHat I have done:

1. https://medium.com/@nehamuthiyan/getting-out-of-the-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-818180ce3940
   I eountered many errors when I tried ./configure and make
2. ["Welcome to emergency mode!" Think it is a fsck problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem)
   Unmounting did not help. My root / is located at sda2.

Comment: Learn about the REISUB reboot; it's more graceful to the system: https://askubuntu.com/a/926476/1157519

Answer (score 0):

I had to unmount and fix sda4 which is my user directory.

```
umount /dev/sda4
fsck -y /dev/sda4
poweroff
```