# GParted takes long time

Tags: gparted

Ubuntu 21.04 hirsute
5.11.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 7 14:22:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

One of the partitions has to be check. I tried to fix it with gparted - check and repair the filesystem. GParted said this might take a long time. The CPU is utilized by gpartedbin about 100%. My question is how long a long time could be? I am waiting for about 6 hours and the progressing bar is still at 90% and not moving.
I am assuming killing this process could corrupt even more data.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How big is partition? What format? Generally it is better not to stop a process in the middle, but 6 hours does seem excessive. Do not power down, but use REISUB, although unless you changed settings I think only R & B work by default. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/11002/alt-sysrq-reisub-doesnt-reboot-my-laptop/334292#334292 `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf`
Then change the number in line 26 from 176 to 244 i.e. kernel.sysrq = 244

Comment: thank you oldfred. Partition was 370G, 300G free, ext4, finally crashed after 8 hours even was the only thread using CPU/MEM, tried to let gparted doing its job. After rebooting the folders were empty, everything gone, no big deal because the backup is done regularly.

Comment: I would then also check drive's Smart Status. You can use Disks and icon in upper right corner or download and run from terminal. The smartmontools package contains two utility programs (smartctl and smartd)