# Grub is not opening after reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Due to solve the freezing problem, I pressed the poweroff button of the computer and the computer was turned down abruptly. Then I turned the computer on but not I am seeing a black screen with a text written as `Reboot and select proper device or Insert Boot Media in selected boot device and press a key`

What should I do to solve this problem without reinstalling `Ubuntu 20.04`?

Also, I tried to use the `TRY Ubuntu` section to repair the boot. But it didn't help. Then I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04. But I received a warning message that says `Error fsyncinc/closing/dev/sda:input/output error`

My priority is to know whether there's a way to fix the problem happens when the computer restarts. I have some data that I need to save.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/dev/sda:input/output error` unfortunately means that your drive is now defective. Replace it.

Comment: First try fsck (e2fsck). http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Forced shutdown often causes file corruption. Then check drive status in Disks & icon in upper right for Smart status of your drive. Or install smart tools directly. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools And try to avoid power shutdowns: https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/11002/alt-sysrq-reisub-doesnt-reboot-my-laptop/334292#334292

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your drive was corrupted when you interrupted it. I'm not sure if there's much more that you can do without taking it to someone to look at the drive. However, if you are fine with wiping your installation, try getting a copy of the GParted live ISO and using that to format your disk. Also, look in to using REISUB keys for killing your installation instead next time. This normally prevents such corruption.

As for the data you need off of your drive, try using the live installation to enter the old installation's files in file manager. If you can do this, you'll be able to grab all your files from it. However, if this isn't possible you'll need to take this drive to somewhere with drive recovery (Best Buy, etc.).

This error has a broad number of things that cause it, so sorry in advanced if my answer isn't related in any way to the problem.

Comment: This answer is actually better than the other one hence the +1. That said, I/O errors always always point to a defective drive.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest that

1. Firstly, Backup Data!
2. use Rufus(open source boot tool) to create a USB key to boot into Ubuntu.
3. Reinstall the grub on disk, in Terminal,

```
# use this if the disk is EFI system
$ sudo grub-install --target x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/media/ubuntu/diskPath/ --efi-directory=/media/ubuntu/diskPath /dev/sdX 
# use this if the disk is legacy system
$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/ubuntu/diskPath /dev/sdX
```

however, since the crash cause grub disable to reboot, I strongly recommend that re-install the Ubuntu because it's most likely some problem on disk. re-format it probably can fix it.
Good luck!

Comment: No, I/O errors almost always point to a defective drive.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I agree with you. just as I strongly recommend, maybe re-install OS/ reformat is the best option. however, as OP wants not to reinstall OS, maybe try reinstall grub is a option.

Comment: But all that is wasted time if the drive is bad -and- it decreases the chances to recover any data if still possible. In those cases the best option is actually to stop using the drive immediately. Also recommended to image it and then work on the image.