# Multiple 0 byte files and empty folders

Tags: hard-drive, kde

I'm using Ubuntu 20-LTS with KDE and have recently had some very strange issues happening.

I typically use Dolphin for file management but lately Dolphin has been hanging during some file copy operations and sometimes even freezing the entire KDE desktop with only the mouse cursor still active - and therefore requiring a reboot to get things working again.

On one such occasion after Dolphin hanging and restarting the system I found that my external USB-NTFS drive had multiple folders totally emptied of all files, along with many other files on the drive still existing but reduced to 0 bytes. I thought there may be something wrong with the USB-NTFS drive, so I reformatted it to exFAT/HPFS and everything seemed to be working fine with the drive for the past couple of days.

Today I had a problem with my Chromium browser not starting so I rebooted and on restart found that all my Chromium and Chrome browser histories had vanished, and also found several other files reduced to 0 bytes on my primary EXT4 Linux file system / SSD drive.

SMART control says that both these drives are fine and show no errors.

Does anyone have any ideas on what may be the issue?  Could this somehow be hardware related?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

As posted in comments in response to request for more info:
Release details using lsb_release -a - reports:

No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 20.10 Release: 20.10 Codename: groovy

Is there more information needed - if so what command(s) should I use to determine the details you need?

Comment: Please be specific with OS & release details.  Ubuntu has both releases that use the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20, these are *snap* only products) and those using *year.month* format (eg. Kubuntu 20.04 LTS). Are you using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS or something else?  (such as KDE Neon).  There is no 20 release that uses KDE as KDE is packaged only in *deb* format for use by *year.month* format products. Your actual stack may provide clues as you've mixed details in what you provided (KDE Neon uses a different stack to Kubuntu)

Comment: Release details using lsb_release -a    
- reports

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy

Is there more information needed - if so what command(s) should I use to determine the details you need?

Comment: Avoid "force" shutdown. See [What's the difference between the magic REISUB reset and holding down the power key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power) Forcing shutdown messes up attached USB drives as they are at the "unsafe to remove" state.