# Ubuntu keeps lagging while scrolling and lags while loading webpages

Tags: 20.04, display

The following is my ubuntu information:-

```
$neofetch

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64
Host: 81WE IdeaPad 3 15IIL05
Kernel: 5.13.0-30-generic
Uptime: 2 mins
Packages: 2774 (dpkg), 1 (flatpak)
Shell: bash 5.0.17
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel i5-1035G1 (8) @ 3.600GHz
GPU: Intel Device 8a56
```

When I scroll pdf files or webpages, my ubuntu keeps lagging. I don't want to reinstall it, hence, why I am asking for help.

I also checked my RAM usage and it seems to be normal. However, CPU usage seems to get high when my computer starts to lag. Below is an image of my CPU usage while I am scrolling a pdf document:-

[image]

This all started when I closed my computer by pressing and holding on the power button once.

Please do tell me what other information I should provide so as to make this issue clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem just by pressing and holding down on the power button. So the issue is solved.

Comment: No, it's not. Please stop doing that and either shutdown properly or reboot. Brute forcing the shutdown will at some point produce errors that may not be easy to correct.

Comment: Instead of shutting down by holding down the power button you can use REISUB, i.e. hold down the `Alt`+`SysRq` (usually `PrtSc` on laptops) buttons and at the same time press the following letters one by one `R`, `E`, `I`, `S`, `U`, `B`. For what this does see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/926476/618353).