# possibly corrupt filesystem after force shutdown?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, data-corruption

(i only have ubuntu installed on this laptop)

i opened what seemed to be a subtitle file and the computer froze entirely so what seemed like the only option was to force shut it down pressing the power button.
next time that i tried to turn it on, i got the following message:

```
error: failure writing sector 0x120f0580 to `hd0`.
```

after that it goes to a "initramfs" screen. i tried typing `exit` but it returns a bunch of error messages and freezes.

then i tried to re-install ubuntu by creating a bootable usb flash drive. however when it gets to the actual installation part, it automatically selects the "something else" option and i can't create any partitions as it only recognizes the usb stick. `fdisk` and `gparted` on the terminal also don't seem to recognize the hard drive.

as i don't understand much about this i'm not sure what to do now. is it possible that my hd is damaged? if not, what would be the easiest way to fix this? is there a way to fix the filesystem through initramfs or the ubuntu live environment? OR if the easiest way to fix this problem would be through a new install, how do i get it to recognize my hd instead of the usb flash drive?

btw, i've seen a lot of people talking about this so i'm not using RAID (not sure what that means exactly but i have manually set it to AHCI through bios when i first installed ubuntu on this machine, and it has always worked perfectly fine until yesterday)

Comment: Hard shutdown can corrupt file system whether Ubuntu or Windows (chkdsk). With Linux and ext4 format, you may then need to run fsck or e2fsck on all ext4 partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Since older answer, but still valid and never accepted, if this works for you, I will convert to answer. Always best to use REISUB to shutdown and make sure all tasks have timed out. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power

Comment: the problem is that when i try to run ```sudo parted -l``` the only thing that shows up is my usb flash drive so i cant run fsck or e2fsck since the partitions aren't there

Comment: Is drive seen by UEFI settings for hardware? Not boot menu?